# Declaring temporary variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, variables, compatibility

I'm migrating from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I've seen from [How to declare a variable in a PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query) that there is no such thing as temporary variables in native sql queries.

Well, I pretty badly need a few... How would I go about mixing in `plpgsql`? Must I create a function and then delete the function in order to get access to a language? that just seems error prone to me and I'm afraid I'm missing something.

EDIT:

```
cmd.CommandText="insert......" +
"declare @app int; declare @gid int;"+
"set @app=SCOPE_IDENTITY();"+ //select scope_identity will give us our RID that we just inserted
"select @gid=MAX(GROUPID) from HOUSEHOLD; set @gid=@gid+1; "+
"insert into HOUSEHOLD (APPLICANT_RID,GROUPID,ISHOH) values "+
"(@app,@gid,1);"+
"select @app";
rid=cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

A direct rip from the application in which it's used. Note we are in the process of converting from SQL server to Postgre. (also, I've figured out the `scope_identity()` bit I think)

Comment: Did you mean temporary table?

Comment: no, variables. Like `declare @foo int;`

Comment: Ah, you mean table variable then (http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx)

Comment: not really, plus thats not postgresql

Comment: can you show a piece of code that you think requires the use of variables?  postgresql is different from sql server, maybe your usage pattern doesn't translate as literally as you hoped.

Comment: ok, I have no edited my question to include that

Comment: Try using Npgsql and a .net var

Comment: @Tobu, this is what I am currently doing. It means though that if the SQL server is not the same as the Web server then it must add on some latency to make 3 queries on the remote SQL server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your schema for the table being inserted?  I'll try and answer based on this assumption of the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE HOUSEHOLD (
    APPLICANT_RID SERIAL,  -- PostgreSQL auto-increment
    GROUPID INTEGER,
    ISHOH INTEGER
);
```

If I'm understanding your intent correctly, in PostgreSQL >= 8.2, the query would then be:

```
INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD (GROUPID, ISHOH)
VALUES ((SELECT COALESCE(MAX(GROUPID)+1,1) FROM HOUSEHOLD), 1)
RETURNING APPLICANT_RID;

-- Added call to the COALESCE function to cover the case where HOUSEHOLD 
-- is empty and MAX(GROUPID) returns NULL
```

In PostgreSQL >= 8.2, any INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE query may have a RETURNING clause that acts like a simple SELECT performed on the result set of the change query.

Comment: I was not aware you could nest selects inside of inserts and such.. I guess I just need to read up more on Ansi SQL(if that is standard anyway)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a language binding, you can hold the variables there.

For example with SQLAlchemy (python):

```
my_var = 'Reynardine'
session.query(User.name).filter(User.fullname==my_var)
```

If you're in psql, you have variables:

```
\set a 5
SELECT :a;
```

And if your logic is in PL/pgSQL:

```
tax := subtotal * 0.06;
```

Comment: I am wanting to do these queries from my own program, not from psql

Comment: Thanks. What language binding are you using?

Comment: plpgsql.. I'm not sure how to use it freestanding though... (like in a sql query without creating a function)

Comment: I was thinking of a library like SQLAlchemy, psycopg2 or ActiveRecord.

Comment: @earlz: You cannot. Procedural languages are for functions/procedures only.

Answer (score 1):

> Must I create a function and then
>   delete the function in order to get
>   access to a language?

Yes, but this shortcoming is going to be removed in PostgreSQL 8.5, [with the addition of DO command](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-do.html). 8.5 is going to be released in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare session variables using plperl - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plperl-global.html

Answer (score 0):

you install a language that you want to use with the CREATE LANGUAGE command for known languages.  Although you can use other languages.

[Language installation docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xplang-install.html)

[CREATE LANGUAGE usage doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createlanguage.html)

You will have to create a function to use it.  If you do not want to make a permanent function in the db then the other choice would be to use a scrip in python or something that uses a postgresql driver to connect to the db and do queries.  You can then manipulate or look through the data in the script.  For instance in python you would install the pygresql library and in your script import pgdb which you can use to connect to the db.

[PyGreSQL Info](http://www.pygresql.org/pgdb.html)

Answer (score -1):

I think that PostgreSQL's [row-type variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) would be the closest thing:

> A variable of a composite type is
>   called a row variable (or row-type
>   variable). Such a variable can hold a
>   whole row of a SELECT or FOR query
>   result, so long as that query's column
>   set matches the declared type of the
>   variable.

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned the post ([How to declare a variable in a PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query)).

I believe there is a suitable answer farther down the chain of solutions if using psql and the \set command:

```
my_db=> \set myvar 5
my_db=> SELECT :myvar  + 1 AS my_var_plus_1;
```

Comment: This seems more like a parameter binding than a session variable.