# No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash

I am trying to get values from postgresql DB using the bash command line : There is an issue trying to get run a select statement from the table.

For example if I execute this select statement, it return successful and gives the value

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432 -t -c "select count(*) from sampledata.sif_work where servicerequesttype='CreatepostgresCase'"
```

However when I tried to add more where statement either hardcoded or variables to the WHERE statement, I got this error :

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <> integer
LINE 1: ...questtype='CreatepostgresCase' and applicationerrorcode!=25 and a...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The script :

```
 #!/bin/bash
errorCodeSuccess=0
errorCodeFailure=30
sampleDbUser=postgres
sampleDBPort=5432

appErrorCodeFailure=25

#hardcoded
psql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432 -t -c "select count(*) from sampledata.sif_work where servicerequesttype='CreatepostgresCase' and applicationerrorcode=25  and pxcreatedatetime>current_date"

#variables used 
psql -U "${sampleDbUser}" -d postgres -p "${sampleDBPort}" -t -c "select count(*) from sampledata.sif_work where servicerequesttype='CreatepostgresCase' and applicationerrorcode!="${appErrorCodeFailure}" and applicationerrorcode!="${errorCodeSuccess}"  and pxcreatedatetime>current_date"
```

Any reason why even though I hardcoded the value, it is still throwing error. Any reason ?

Comment: Is `applicationerrorcode` of type varchar ? If so, then you update your query with `and applicationerrorcode!='25'` or `and applicationerrorcode!=25 :: text`

Comment: Because it has nothing to do adding additional predicates to the WHERE clause. It has to with the additional predicate is *invalid*. The error message clearly indicates you are trying to compare a string (character varying) to an integer. You *cannot do that*. Rewrite operand 25 as a string (as '25') or as indicates CAST it to one (cast 25 as character varying or 25::text.

Comment: I now put a single quote around the variable is now working even though the variable is already declared = '25'. I still need to put single quote around that too '"${errorCodeSuccess}" '

Comment: Setting your data type choices aside, you can simply add a single quote `'` before you close your query string where you insert the variable, then another one after you reopen it `"select ... and applicationerrorcode != '"${appErrorCodeFailure}"' and applicationerrorcode != '"${errorCodeSuccess}"' ..."`. PostgreSQL understands `25` as an integer literal but `'25'` will be interpreted as a text literal. You can also *not* close the string at all - bash evaluates $ expressions in double quotes: `"select ... and applicationerrorcode != '${appErrorCodeFailure}' ..."`

Comment: Thank you all. All good now

Comment: See what happens in bash if you do `a=5; b='5'; c="'5'"; echo $a $b $c;` - only `c` will keep the single quotes in the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL understands `25` as an integer literal but `'25'` will be interpreted as a [text literal/string constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS), which would [work](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/typeconv-oper.html) with your `character varying` type column.

You could add the single quote `'` before you close and after you open the double quotes `"`, but you also don't need to close that double-quoted string at all - [bash evaluates `$` expressions in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/5298879):

```bash
errorCodeSuccess=0
errorCodeFailure=30
sampleDbUser=postgres
sampleDBPort=5432

appErrorCodeFailure=25

#hardcoded
psql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432 -t \
    -c "select count(*) 
        from   sampledata.sif_work 
        where  servicerequesttype='CreatepostgresCase' 
        and    applicationerrorcode='25'--single quotes indicate a text literal
        and    pxcreatedatetime>current_date"

#variables used 
psql -U "${sampleDbUser}" -d postgres -p "${sampleDBPort}" -t \
    -c "select count(*)
        from   sampledata.sif_work
        where  servicerequesttype='CreatepostgresCase'
        and    applicationerrorcode!='${appErrorCodeFailure}'
        and    applicationerrorcode!='${errorCodeSuccess}'
        and    pxcreatedatetime>current_date; "
```

You already knew you can safely use single quotes within a double-quoted string, looking at `servicerequesttype='CreatepostgresCase'`.

You can also make the single quotes a part of the value:

```bash
#already doesn't work:
errorCodeSuccess=0
#same effect:
errorCodeSuccess='0'  
#this will be interpreted as a column named "0":
errorCodeSuccess='"0"' 
#"0" would be a valid name, but I doubt you have one or want one

#this will work:
errorCodeSuccess="'0'"
errorCodeFailure="'30'"
sampleDbUser=postgres
sampleDBPort=5432
psql -U "${sampleDbUser}" -d postgres -p "${sampleDBPort}" -t \
    -c "select count(*)
        from   sampledata.sif_work
        where  servicerequesttype='CreatepostgresCase'
        and    applicationerrorcode != ${appErrorCodeFailure}
        and    applicationerrorcode != ${errorCodeSuccess}
        and    pxcreatedatetime>current_date; "
```

Keep in mind that it's always unsafe to construct queries this way - both in terms of security and convenience. You could start improving this with [`psql -v`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7389416/5298879).

Comment: I have accepted the answer also. All of you guys pointed my error. Cheers