# Using "If" condition in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I like to use "IF" condition in where clause. From various threads, I understand that one of the options is CASE expression but I couldn't figure it out.

Sample Code :

```
select * from sampleTable
where 
  If @taxtype = 'P' then
    (taxtype = 'P' or  (taxtype = 'E' and code in ('MER','SER')))
  Else
    (taxtype = 'E' and code not in ('MER','SER'))
  End If
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from sampleTable
where 
  case when @taxtype = 'P' then
    (taxtype = 'P' or  (taxtype = 'E' and code in ('MER','SER')))
  Else
    (taxtype = 'E' and code not in ('MER','SER'))
  end
```

[Looks like](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html) this'll work with Postres

Edit:

Leaving my original answer because the gist works but [Postgres doesn't have a concept of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query) like other RDBMSs so I re-wrote this as

```
WITH myconstants as (SELECT 'P'::text as vtaxtype)

select * from sampleTable
where 
  case when (select vTaxType from myconstants) = 'P' then
    (taxtype = 'P' or  (taxtype = 'E' and code in ('MER','SER')))
  Else
    (taxtype = 'E' and code not in ('MER','SER'))
  end;
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58ece/10) showing that

Comment: Seems this is not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815761/syntax-error-when-using-case-in-where-clause

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can do that by adding an OR

```
select * from sampleTable
where 
  (
    @taxtype = 'P' 
    AND
    (taxtype = 'P' or  (taxtype = 'E' and code  in ('MER','SER')))
  )
  OR
  (
    taxtype = 'E' 
    AND 
    code in ('MER','SER')
  )
```

An example of how to do it with case statements (for the sake of the question at hand).  This works in SQL Server

```
select * from @sampleTable
where 
  case when @taxtype = 'P' then
    case when (taxtype = 'P' or  (taxtype = 'E' and code in ('MER','SER'))) then 1 else 0 end
  Else
    case when (taxtype = 'E' and code not in ('MER','SER')) then 1 else 0 end
  end =1
```