# postgres - unrecognized configuration parameter

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, session-variables, user-defined-variables

I use the following query in my trigger to store user's ID for further use:

```sql
SELECT set_config('session.my_username', 'john', false);
```

Later, in other trigger I use it this way:

```sql
SELECT current_setting('session.my_username');
```

It works like a charm when parameter is set (first query is executed), which happens when user uses the application.

The point is, that IF developer / supporter tries to modify data that calls second trigger USING some database tool, first trigger does not get executed. In this case, developer / supporter gets `unrecognized configuration parameter` error message.

My question is, how to avoid such situation? Is there any way to know that configuration parameter is not set before I call `SELECT current_setting()`?

Comment: `select current_setting('session.my_username', true);` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET

Answer (score 0):

For [set_config()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET), `false` in the 3rd argument means ***the new value applies to the current session*** and `true` in the 3rd argument means ***the new value applies to the current transaction*** as shown below:

```sql
SELECT set_config('my.num', '2', false);
SELECT current_setting('my.num'); -- 2
BEGIN;
SELECT set_config('my.num', '4', true);
SELECT current_setting('my.num'); -- 4
COMMIT;
SELECT current_setting('my.num'); -- 2
```

In addition, there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528168/postgresql-unrecognized-configuration-parameter/77649482#77649482) when you use the [custom option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) which you've never set (even once) in the session and there is not [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528168/postgresql-unrecognized-configuration-parameter/77649482#77649482) when you use the custom option which you've set (at least once) in the session as shown below:

```sql
SELECT current_setting('my.num'); -- Error
BEGIN;
SELECT set_config('my.num', '4', true);
SELECT current_setting('my.num'); -- 4
COMMIT;
SELECT current_setting('my.num'); -- Nothing is returned without error
```