# PostgreSQL : function set_config(unknown, bigint, boolean) doesn't exist

Tags: database, postgresql, configuration-files, custom-options

I am trying to use the `current_setting()` and `set_config()` functions for plpgpsq, to change the value of a custom setting I've added to my postgresql.conf file.

Here's what I added to the end of my postgresql.conf file :

```sql
IntegrityPackage.NestLevel = 0
```

After restarting the PostgreSQL service, here's what I get when I want to see the setting's value :

```sql
SELECT current_setting('IntegrityPackage.NestLevel');
    
current_setting |
----------------|
0               |
```

However, when I try to edit the value, I get an error message :

```sql
SELECT set_config('IntegrityPackage.NestLevel', 0, false);
    
ERROR: function set_config(unknown, bigint, boolean) doesn't exist.
Hint: No function corresponds to given name and argument types
You must add explicit type conversions
```

(Vaguely translated from french since the error message was in french)

There is very little documnetation about this, therefore I'm stuck and I can't think of another way to do this.

*Edit* - the exact error text (in psql 9.2 / postgresql 10.0) is:

```sql
ERROR:  function set_config(unknown, integer, boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT set_config('my.foo',obj_id::int ,false) FROM objects ...
                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work:

```sql
SELECT set_config('IntegrityPackage.NestLevel', '0', false);
```

Comment: But NOTE: `'IntegrityPackage.NestLevel'` is _*NOT*_ an INT or BIGINT.  It's a _string_.  It only _looks_ like a number.


To get a number back, you need to do:  

    `select current_setting('IntegrityPackage.NestLevel')::BIGINT;`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  function set_config(unknown, integer, boolean) does not exist

When `2` doesn't have `''` to set a [custom option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) with [set_config()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) as shown below:

```sql
                         -- ↓
SELECT set_config('my.num', 2, false);
```

So, I set `2` with `''` as shown below, then I could set the custom option without error:

```sql
                         -- ↓ ↓
SELECT set_config('my.num', '2', false);
```