# Declaring and assigning values to variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters

First of all, I'm a total beginner in SQL. I have a table with 50+ columns, and now I'm doing calculations (on created temp table), but in some formulas, I got parameters, for example: A = 3

(A*(Column5 + Column7))/2

So, what is the best way to assign a value to a parameter?

This is what I was thinking about

```
DECLARE A          DOUBLE PRECISION:=3;
```

But I don't know how implementing it.

Comment: "assign a value to a parameter and use it later".  I don't understand this.  Are you asking about the scripting language?  Are you asking about a way to define a function?  When you are executing a single query, there is no "later".

Comment: My bad, sorry. I need to use it in a query or multiple queries, but I'm not sure if I need it assign for each query again or not. As I said, I'm a total beginner. I need help with calculating that formula with parameters, there would be everything from start to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The with option essentially creates a temp table that you can reference in a sql statement within the same transaction.

Your best bet is to create a function and then pass it the value of the parameter at run time. eg.

```
CREATE FUNCTION addColumns(
                          A integer, 
                          firstColumn integer, 
                          secondColumn integer
                            ) 
RETURNS integer
AS 
RETURN (A*(firstColumn + secondColumn))/2
LANGUAGE SQL 
IMMUTABLE;
```

Then use this in your query like:

```
 select addColumns(3, column5, column7) 
 from [table];
```

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand you want to store values using variables.
This is already answered here : [How to declare a variable in a PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query)

There are many solutions there, but I particularly like using a [WITH clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) as pointed in one of the answers, when using plain SQL. For more fancy things, you should write proper stored procedures.