# Mocking Postgresql now() function for testing

Tags: node.js, postgresql, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following stack

- Node/Express backend
- Postgresql 10 database
- Mocha for testing
- Sinon for mocking

I have written a bunch of end-to-end tests to test all my webservices. The problem is that some of them are time dependent (as in "give me the modified records of the last X seconds").

`sinon` is pretty good at mocking all the time/dated related stuff in Node, however I have a `modified` field in my Postgresql tables that is populated with a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_modified_column()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.modified = now();
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The problem of course is that `sinon` can't override that `now()` function.

Any idea on how I could solve this? The problem is not setting a specific date at the start of the test, but advancing time faster than real-time (in one of my tests I want to change some stuff in the database, advance the 'current time' with one day, change some more stuff in the database and do webservice calls to see the result).

I can figure out a few solutions myself, but they all involve changing the application code and making it less elegant. I don't think your application code should be impacted by the fact that you want to test it.

Comment: You could write your own `now()` function, then use that in the trigger. In production the function would do the same as `now()` but for testing it might simply get the value from a database table

Comment: I am no database expert, but can I just override native functions in postgresql?

Comment: I didn't mean "override". Just create your own, and use _that_ in your trigger

Comment: That amounts to changing application logic because you are writing tests

Comment: If you can, you should pass a mocked time to SQL parameter. It's more consistent.

Comment: Link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69988/how-can-i-fake-inet-client-addr-for-unit-tests-in-postgresql

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to create a mock `now()` function:

- Use schema "override" to define a function: `override.now()`
- Use `search_path` to make Postgres look in the `override` schema ([how to fake a function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69988/how-can-i-fake-inet-client-addr-for-unit-tests-in-postgresql))
- Abuse a configuration parameter to set the time: `'test.freeze_time'` ([how to declare a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29469454/134904)

Let's define the function first:

```sql
set session test.freeze_time = '';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION override.now() 
  RETURNS timestamptz IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS 
$$
BEGIN
    if current_setting('test.freeze_time') = '' then
        return pg_catalog.now();
    else
        return current_setting('test.freeze_time')::timestamptz;
    end if;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Now this is how you enable it:

```sql
set search_path = override,pg_temp,"$user",public,pg_catalog;
set session test.freeze_time = '2023-03-03 00:00:00Z';
```

```
test=# SELECT now();
          now           
------------------------
 2023-03-03 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

We have to mention `pg_catalog` explicitly [because](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/211089/47804):

> If pg_catalog is not in the path then it will be searched before searching any of the path items.

Also, unfortunately, we cannot use `pg_temp` to define our function [because](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/211089/47804):

> It is never searched for function or operator names.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this very neat gist](https://gist.github.com/thehesiod/d0314d599c721216f075375c667e2d9a) which provides a fake `NOW()` function that lives in a separate schema.  You load it into your test database and then modify the search path of each testing session to search `override` before `pg_catalog`.  Two functions `freeze_time` and `unfreeze_time` are provided to enable and disable frozen time.

Comment: Could you provide more details, how to install the gist and use it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: Create your own `mock_now()` with `mock_dates` table:

```sql
create table mock_dates (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    mock_date timestamptz not null
);

create or replace function mock_now()
    returns timestamptz
    as $$
    declare
        RET timestamptz;
    begin
        -- Delete first added date and assign it to RET
        delete from mock_dates where id in (
            select id from mock_dates order by id asc limit 1
        )
        returning mock_dates.mock_date into RET;

        -- If no deletion happened just return the current timestamp
        if RET is null then
            return now();
        end if;

        -- Otherwise return the mocked date
        return RET;
    end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

And insert some mocked dates

```sql
insert into mock_dates (mock_date) values ('2001-03-11 02:34:00'::timestamptz);
insert into mock_dates (mock_date) values ('2002-05-22 01:49:00'::timestamptz);
```

and use `mock_now()` instead of `now()`. It will return the timestamps inserted to the `mock_dates` table once (first in first out).

When the table is empty it will work like the default `now()`.

Just ensure the `mock_dates` table is empty in production

Or you could even define a different function for production which does not even try to read the `mock_dates` table.

Comment: This has the downside of requiring a lookup even when there's nothing to mock.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, DB internal stuff is always hard to test from application code.  In my experience, the best thing to do is to just verify the record's state.

So, rather than testing specifically that the now function is called internally, write a test that creates a new record, then verify that record has created and modified fields set. At that point they should equal each other, and probably be within the last second or two, so that's all stuff you can write assertions around.

Then you write another test that changes some value in the record, and write assertions that the modified stamp is different from the created stamp, is more recent, and probably within the last second d or two.

Comment: Yeah, but that is off topic. I don't want to test the database. I want in my end to end test see that some stuff that was modified a week ago comes back in my "what stuff has been modified a week ago" web services (oversimplification but I hope you understand it :) ).

Comment: That wasn't clear from your original question.  If you're testing that stuff is properly returned based on its parameters (timestamp or otherwise) then you need to have a test dataset that's seeded with known data.