# Use pl/pgsql variable in calculated columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I am building a query for a report and it has a lot of repeated const values in calculated columns. Simplified example:

```
select
    c.title || ' corp', -- more than one column appending this
    to_char(c.last_contact, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') -- this format is used for other columns as well
from clients c;
```

I want to extract those repeated const values into variables and use variables instead. In TSQL I could achieve it with code like this:

```
declare
    @suffix varchar(8) = ' corp',
    @dateFormat varchar(16) = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI' -- let's pretend that's a correct format string for TSQL

select
    c.title + @suffix,
    convert(varchar(32), c.last_contact, @dateFormat)
from clients c
```

I'm trying to achieve same behavior in pl/pgsql with this:

```
do $$
declare
    suffix text := ' corp';
    date_format text := 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI';
begin
    select
        c.title || suffix,
        to_char(c.last_contact, date_format)
    from clients c;
end;
$$;
```

And it breaks:

```
ERROR: query has no destination for result data
  Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at SQL statement
1 statement failed.
```

So far I've only found examples of using variables in WHERE block, but none in SELECT block.

I've seen `EXECUTE 'select ...' WITH` examples, but my quick attempt of using that

```
do $$
declare
    process_start timestamp := now();
begin
    execute 'select $1;'    
    using process_start;
end;
$$;
```

just reports `DO executed successfully` without actually selecting anything.

Is there a way to use pl/pgsql variables in calculated columns?

Any other alternatives to achieve this in postgres?

Comment: What do you want to do with that value? You have to store it somewhere. Your example doesn't make sense to me. Why PL/pgSQL? Why not simply use `now()` in your query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used `now()` as an example, because I need process start date as one of the columns. The process takes more than a second to run and I don't expect `now()` to be same value as the moment the query begun. I also have text constants that need appending to some columns.

Comment: You need to explain the underlying problem, not the "solution" you think you need. Also: `now()` doesn't change during a transaction: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tank you for clarifying `now()` behavior. Please see updated question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , can you explain how does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query answer my question? I don't have problems declaring variables or printing their values. I have problems with using them in calculated columns.

Comment: You can not use variables in SQL queries, simple as that. And you can't have a `do` block that returns a result. The duplicate questions shows you various workarounds for using variables in queries as you are doing in the T-SQL example. PL/pgSQL is **not** a replacement for that if you want to run queries (using variables) and **see** their result.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with this value? Puzzling example. 
Using a `FUNCTION` it could be solved more or less like this

```
create or replace function my_function()
returns timestamp as $$
declare
    process_start timestamp := now();
begin
    return process_start;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

If you really want to ignore the result of the only select in your code, you can use `PERFORM`

```
do $$
declare
    process_start timestamp := now();
begin
    perform (select process_start);
end;
$$;
```

Comment: I don't want to ignore it. I updated example code in the question to illustrate my problem a little better.

Answer (score 0):

To use `SELECT` in PL/pgSQL, you have to specify an `INTO` clause:

```
SELECT process_start, s.title || suffix
   INTO var1, var2
   FROM ...
```