# \set command in EDB Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

In EDB Postgres, `\set` command is used to set variables, like for example `\set detpno 80`  and while inserting we can use `:deptno` instaed of actual value like

```
insert into dept values (:deptno, 'SALES', 'HYD');
```

it's working fine, but when i use it in Procedure or anonymous block its throwing error.

simple anonymous block

```
begin
insert into dept values (:deptno, 'SALES', 'LONDON');
end;
```

when i execute this block,  I am getting below error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
>   LINE 2: insert into dept1 values (:deptno, 'SALES', 'BAN');

Please help me out to use \set variable in procedures or functions.

Comment: Hi Suresh Welcome to StackOverFlow. Could you \d+ tablename for us? so we can replicate your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a variable in a PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query)

Answer (score 0):

The substitution of :varname with something that was previously \set is a feature of a particular database client, namely "psql" (although maybe other clients have emulated this behavior).  It is not a feature of the database itself.  The database doesn't see the :varname, it only sees what it was substituted with.

When you use an anonymous code block, you are by-passing the client's substitution behavior.

Perhaps you should create a function, which declares what parameters it takes in a proper way, rather than using shell-like variable interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

The psql variables cannot be used inside server side code - anonymous blocks. It is just not allowed - the substitution is blocked inside string. You can use a workaround.

1. set a custom guc variable (custom configuration value). The prefix 'xx' is requested.

   ```
   postgres=# \set myval AHOJ
   postgres=# select set_config('xx.myval', :'myval', false);
    ┌────────────┐
    │ set_config │
    ╞════════════╡
    │ AHOJ       │
    └────────────┘
   (1 row)
   ```
2. Now you can read the value by function `current_setting` on server side

   ```
   postgres=# do $$
   begin
     raise notice '%', current_setting('xx.myval');
   end;
   $$;
   NOTICE:  AHOJ
   DO
   ```

Currently there are not any other way how to do it. This is Postgres - but EDB is very similar in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel Stehule