# SQL - Using WITH to declare variable on INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use `WITH` to declare a variable for a query when doing an `INSERT INTO`.
I'm following https://stackoverflow.com/a/16552441/2923526 which gives the following example for a `SELECT` query:

```
WITH myconstants (var1, var2) as (
   values (5, 'foo')
)
SELECT *
FROM somewhere, myconstants
WHERE something = var1
   OR something_else = var2;
```

---

I tried the following with no luck:

```
playground> CREATE TABLE foo (id numeric)
CREATE TABLE

playground> WITH consts (x) AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo VALUES (x)
column "x" does not exist
LINE 1: WITH consts (x) AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo VALUES (x)
                                                                ^

playground> WITH consts (x) AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo VALUES (consts.x)
missing FROM-clause entry for table "consts"
LINE 1: ...consts (x) AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo VALUES (consts.x)
                                                              ^

playground> WITH consts (x) AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo VALUES (consts.x) FROM consts
syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: ...AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo VALUES (consts.x) FROM const...
                                                             ^

playground> WITH consts (x) AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo FROM consts VALUES (consts.x)
syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: WITH consts (x) AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo FROM consts ...
                                                        ^
```

---

Note I am begginer to SQL so I'm looking to avoid solutions that imply using PLPGSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
WITH consts (x) AS (VALUES (2)) INSERT INTO foo SELECT x FROM consts
```

That is: the `WITH` clause creates a *derived table*, that you can then use within the main query; so you actually need to `SELECT ... FROM` the common table expression.

Comment: That works, thank you.  
I'm confused about why the second `VALUES` inside the `INSERT INTO` is not needed, but guessing that's independent from the `WITH` statement (just syntax about `INSERT INTO`) right?

Comment: You are correct. See [Postgres Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html). Select your specific version if necessary. Stripped down to the basics the are 2 insert formats: Format 1.  *Insert (...) Values (...)*.  Format 2. *Insert(...) Select ... from table_name* As @FranciscoFigari indicated the CTE (with) just supplied the *table_name* for Format 2.