# PostgreSQL interval invalidate

Tags: postgresql

```
 select date,
    to_char(shares, '99g999g999g999') as shares,
    to_char(trades, '99g999g999') as trades,
    to_char(dollars, 'L99g999g999g999') as dollars
    from facebook
    where date >= '2017-02-01'  + interval '1 months'
    order by date;
```

```
message: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "2017-02-01"
LINE 6:  where date >= '2017-02-01'  + interval '1 months
```

I know there is one way to do it by declare a date variable.
so the code would be

```
 date >= date: 'Variable' + interval '1 month'
```

But I don't know how to set a date variable in PGadmin.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Would you please give me some links about how to declare variables in PGadmin. Thanks.

Comment: SQL (at least standard SQL) has no "variables". You would need to use PL/pgSQL if you want a variable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query) for some workarounds

Answer (score 1):

`'2017-02-01'` is treated as a string literal, not as a date literal. To make Postgres recognize it as a proper `date` value, use a proper date literal.

I prefer using ANSI date literals, which are strings prefixed with the keyword `date`

```
where date >= date '2017-02-01'  + interval '1 months'
```

Note that your choice of the column name `date` makes this quite confusing. The `date` on the left side refers to the *column*. The `date` prefixing the string literal refers to the *data type* name. To avoid the confusion, don't use reserved words (e.g. data types) as column names.