# How to execute WHILE LOOP in SQL (PostgreSQL/pgAdmin 4)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, while-loop, syntax-error

I am trying to run this simple WHILE loop in pgAdmin's query tool:

```sql
DECLARE @counter INT = 1;
    
WHILE @counter <= 5
BEGIN
  PRINT @counter;
  SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

The desired result is just a list from 1 to 5, but my pgAdmin is returning this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
> LINE 1: DECLARE @counter INT = 1;

I'm an undergrad in a non-IT course, so I hope you consider this in your explanations. Thank you!
([code source](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-while/))

Comment: Does [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query) answer your question?

Comment: You should tag your question with sql-server not postgresql.  The syntax is different with each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is from `SQL Server`, not `PostgreSQL`. You should try something like this:

```
do $$
declare 
   counter integer := 0;
begin
   while counter < 5 loop
      raise notice 'Counter %', counter;
      counter := counter + 1;
   end loop;
end$$;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much for clearing this up! I appreciate it :) Is there a way to be able to just print the counter without having it output "NOTICE"?

Comment: @deanne: why not simply use `select * from generate_series(0,5)`

Answer (score 0):

> This answer assumed the source was postgres syntax, not sql-server,
> due to the incorrect tag of the question.

SQL identifiers and key words must ***begin with a letter*** (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($).

Answer (score 0):

You create the [DO statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) with a [WHILE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS-WHILE) as shown below.

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE 
  counter INT := 1;
BEGIN
  WHILE counter <= 5 LOOP
    RAISE INFO 'Counter: %', counter;
      counter := counter + 1;
  END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Then, you can get the result below:

```
INFO:  Counter: 1
INFO:  Counter: 2
INFO:  Counter: 3
INFO:  Counter: 4
INFO:  Counter: 5
DO
```