# postgres - How to assign a result count to a variable and do a select query based on that

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a from T-SQL and MS SQL Server background and struggling with PostgreSQL. I need to declare a variable, do a count query, save the result of the count in the variable; then based, on the count assign a date to another variable, and then do a select query with that assigned date to return its result set.
The problem is when I declare a variable without a `DO $$` block, like so:

`DECLARE num_rows bigint;` I get:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "bigint"

> LINE 1: DECLARE num_rows bigint;

And if I try within the `DO $$` block, I get the following error on the `SELECT`:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data

> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 35 at SQL statement
> SQL state: 42601

This is what I am trying:

```
DO $$
DECLARE num_rows bigint;
DECLARE end_date timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(my_table.id) 
INTO num_rows
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.something = 1;

IF num_rows > 500 THEN
end_date = '2022-12-03';
END IF;

SELECT * FROM another_table WHERE some_date < end_date;

END $$;
```

Is there any way to accomplish this or similar in PostgreSQL? I cannot use functions because it is a legacy database and I cannot do DDL changes to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]++query+has+no+destination+for+result+data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/how-to-declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C136.4549

Comment: But you don't really need variables to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the links. I have seen them before but most of them suggest using a function, which I am constrained not to use. CTE is another option but it doesn't let me specify something like "use this date if the count exceeds x, otherwise use that date".

Comment: Sure it's possible: https://dbfiddle.uk/0uXanIYd

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, it does! Thanks a bunch for the query!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)in row `end_date = '2022-12-03'` you need a semicolon

2)in last select statement you must use `execute`

I think this will work:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
  num_rows bigint;
  end_date timestamp with time zone;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(my_table.id) 
INTO num_rows
FROM my_table
WHERE my_table.something = 1;

IF num_rows > 500 THEN
end_date = '2022-12-03';
END IF;

execute 'SELECT * FROM another_table WHERE some_date <'|| end_date;

END $$;
```

You can also try to run something like this:

```
with mydate as(
    select case when (select count(*) from mytable where something = 1)>500 then '2022-12-03' end as end_date,
    (select count(*) from mytable where something = 1) as num_rows
    )
select * from another_table a,mydate b where a.some_date>end_date;
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply. Terribly sorry that semicolon was a copy-past error. I have amended it now. I will try the execute way and let you know. But is there another way where I won't need to form/run a dynamic query?

Comment: Unfortunately, doing `execute` runs the query but does not return the result of the `select`. In pgAdmin, I see "Query returned successfully" in the "Messages" panel and "No data output. Execute a query to get output" in the "Data output" panel.

Comment: this will work if you create a function that returns a query. I now realized that you just want to run a query. But it's not quite clear why you need to use a parameter  for a static number like the count of rows and a date. I mean the last select is from another table. Can you please give some more information about what you need to do?

Comment: I am trying to cut short the date range in the interest of performance. 500, in this case, is my page limit. So, if I can find 500 records in the first five days of the specified date range, I want to avoid searching the whole date range. I've simplified the example in the question to keep it focussed.

Comment: @AbubakarMehmood: if that is used for paging, then I would expect some kind of application code behind where you can easily store the result of a query in a variable. Why do everything in SQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I did a mix of the CTE approach and shifting some logic to the application code.

Comment: @mikasa Thanks a lot. The CTE approach worked but instead of joining with `mydate`, I used a subquery to select `end_date` from it like @a_horse_with_no_name suggested in his comment on the OP because it was much faster.