# How does `now()` work as part of an SQL insert statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL statement like this:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select
    value1,
    value2,
    now(),
    now()
from
    othertable inner join anotherothertable on somecolumn = someothercolumn;
```

The `select` component of this query will return many hundreds of thousands of rows.

How will the call to `now()` behave?

- Will it return the same value for all rows inserts?
- Will it return the same value in the same insert, given that it appears to be called twice per single row insertion?

I want to perform this insert such that `now()` is called once, and that value is fixed and used when inserting all the rows and data. I am not sure if this query will behave this way or not.

Since there is no way to do something like `current_timestamp = now()` in SQL and use `current_timestamp` as an argument in place of the two calls to `now()`, I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query) has some suggestions declaring a variable and storing `now()` in it

Comment: Declare a variable and use it.

Comment: `now()` is defined to be the time of the transaction started, see the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: 1) Per [Current Date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT): *transaction_timestamp() is equivalent to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ... now() is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to transaction_timestamp()*. So `now()` = `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. 2) `now()` locks the time at the start of the transaction for the duration of the transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is thoroughly documented at [Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) but, essentially, your code is fine as is if your intention is to have the same time in every row. It'll return the same value for each individual statement, or even the whole transaction.

You can do a quick test:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT now();
-- Wait a few seconds
SELECT now();

ROLLBACK;
```

```
docker=# START TRANSACTION;
START TRANSACTION
docker=*# SELECT now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2023-12-20 11:55:11.761564+00
(1 row)

docker=*# SELECT now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2023-12-20 11:55:11.761564+00
(1 row)

docker=*# ROLLBACK;
ROLLBACK
docker=#
```

Answer (score 1):

The calls to function 'now' in your statement return the same time for all rows in
your statement. The time returned is the time the current transaction was started,
which is at the time of the current statement or an earlier statement in the
transaction.

The documentation for that is in the Postgres manual, [9.9.5. Current Date/Time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT).

Here is a summary:

| function | standard? | which time? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CURRENT_DATE | yes | transaction |
| CURRENT_TIME | yes | transaction |
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | yes | transaction |
| CURRENT_TIME(precision) | yes | transaction |
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(precision) | yes | transaction |
| LOCALTIME | yes | transaction |
| LOCALTIMESTAMP | yes | transaction |
| LOCALTIME(precision) | yes | transaction |
| LOCALTIMESTAMP(precision) | yes | transaction |
| transaction_timestamp() | no | transaction |
| statement_timestamp() | no | statement |
| clock_timestamp | no | clock time |
| timeofday | no | clock time |
| now() | no | transaction |

So, you don't need to put the time into a 'variable'. If for some reason, you still
wanted to do that, you can isolate the time into a 'variable' with the help of a
common table expression (WITH query), without leaving SQL:

```
WITH my_time(t) AS ( VALUES (now()) )
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select
    value1,
    value2,
    t,
    t
from my_time,
     othertable
join anotherothertable on somecolumn = someothercolumn
```

Answer (score -1):

Declaring and using a variable is best option IMHO.

```
create table table1 (col1 int, col2 int, col3 timestamp, col4 timestamp);

DO $$
 DECLARE _now timestamp;
 
BEGIN
  select now() into _now;
  
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
select
    x.v,
    x.v*10,
    _now,
    _now
from
    generate_series(1, 10) x(v);
END $$;

select * from table1;
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 2 | 20 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 3 | 30 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 4 | 40 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 5 | 50 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 6 | 60 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 7 | 70 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 8 | 80 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 9 | 90 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |
| 10 | 100 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 | 2023-12-20 11:35:43.987329 |

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/upZIZRxk)

Comment: This is presumably non-standard SQL? That's ok - but I'm interested to know what is the name of this "dialect" ?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant, you could specify the language dialect. Defaults to plpgsql.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant, it is called anonymous code block, check on online documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html

Comment: Why would you do this? This doesn't change anything in the end result, it's just more code to write, test and maintain. NOW() is already set when the transaction starts, you don't have to do it again. (you can't)

Comment: Please check https://dbfiddle.uk/xdOBs2vD and try to get a different value for NOW() once the transaction has started

Comment: @FrankHeikens, for now() it is the case, not for any function. If one does it for a function\ likely would do it for all. It is better to use variables for things that need to be executed once. You could directly use as well.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Please share an example that shows the benefits. Your statement doesn’t match my experience

Comment: @FrankHeikens try clock_timestamp() for example.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Yes clock_timestamp() behaves differently, see the manual. But that's not the question, the question is about NOW(). And your code is pretty strange when you need NOW(), there is no point in creating a variable _now when you already have now() and both will have the same value anyway. The entire do-statement is obsolete. Why writing all the additional code when the result will be exactly the same without the additional code? And even for clock_timestamp() you most likely don't want to use a variable

Comment: @FrankHeikens, read what did I say. I didn't say I was suggesting it for only now().