# User-defined variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dynamic-variables, user-variables

I have the following MySQL script which I want to implement in PostgreSQL.

```sql
SET @statement = search_address_query;
      PREPARE dynquery FROM @statement;
      EXECUTE dynquery;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynquery;
```

How can I define user-defined variable `@statement` using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you simply `EXECUTE search_address_query;`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Postgres does not normally use variables in plain SQL. But you *can* do that, too:

```
SET foo.test = 'SELECT bar FROM baz';

SELECT current_setting('foo.test');
```

Read about [Customized Options in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html).

In [PostgreSQL 9.1 or earlier you needed to declare `custom_variable_classes`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-custom.html) before you could use that.

However, You **cannot** [`EXECUTE` dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) without a PL (procedural language). You would use a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command for executing ad-hoc statements (but you cannot return data from it). Or use [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) to create a function that executes dynamic SQL (and can return data in any fashion imaginable).

Be sure to safeguard against SQL injection when using dynamic SQL.

Related:

- [Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query)

Comment: how long does a custom setting persist? is it only for a session? is it globally accessible by other sessions? does it persist after service restart?

Comment: @Reinsbrain: Depends how you set it. Settings in `postgresql.conf` are preset for every connection. The effect of `SET` is for the duration of the current session and only visible in the same session. `SET LOCAL` only for the transaction. There are more ways to set options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30179814/939860

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can set the [custom options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) `my.num` and `my.first.name` as variables as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942/declare-a-variable-in-a-postgresql-query/77591709#77591709) explains how to declare user-defined variables in detail:

```sql
SET my.num = 2;
SET my.first.name = 'John';
```

Or, you can set the custom options with [set_config()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) as shown below:

```sql
SELECT set_config('my.num', '2', false);
SELECT set_config('my.first.name', 'John', false);
```

Then, you must use [current_setting()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET) to get the values of the custom options `my.num` and `my.first.name` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.num');
 current_setting
-----------------
 2
(1 row)
```

```sql
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.first.name');
 current_setting
-----------------
 John
(1 row)
```

Next for example, you can use [\set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-SET) to set the number `2` to `num` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# \set num 2
postgres=# SELECT :num;
 ?column?
----------
        2
(1 row)
```

And, you can use `\set` to set the text `John Smith` with `''` to `name` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# \set name 'John Smith'
postgres=# SELECT :'name';
  ?column?
------------
 John Smith
(1 row)
```