# How do I declare variables in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, variables, psql, pgadmin

If I am in the psql terminal then I can declare and use a variable like this:

```
\set message_id soifsdaofisd.gmail.com;
select * from emails where message_id = ':message_id';
```

How can I do this in pgAdmin?

I get an error when ever I try this in pgAdmin:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CALAdkA4YC0" LINE 3: set message_id
>   soifsdaofisd.gmail.com.

Answer (score 33):

When trying to run scripts in pgAdmin I wanted the something similar where i wanted to store a value to use across multiple queries. This is what I found which is similar to SQL

```
set session vars.batch_id = '82';

select * from batches where batch_id = current_setting('vars.batch_id')::int;
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer, works perfectly in pgadmin

Comment: Doesn't work for me I get a syntax error

Answer (score 18):

`\set` is a feature of psql (the interactive command line terminal) and not available in pgAdmin.

PostgreSQL does not normally use variables in plain SQL. You can use [PL/pgSQL code](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) in an anonymous code block ([`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement) or in a [function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc.html) or [procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xproc.html).

Or you can (ab)use [**"customized options"**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html), for text-only server-side "variables", independent of the client:

```
SET foo.test = 'SELECT bar FROM baz';
SELECT current_setting('foo.test');
```

Details:

- [User-defined variables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql/14261927#14261927)

Other options:

- [Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query/13317628#13317628)

Comment: Does anyone else think this is a ridiculous limitation in postgres?

Comment: `declare @mytbl, @maxid;
set @mytbl = 'sometable';
set @maxid = someid;
select count(*) from @mytbl where id <= @maxid;` when I click on "execute PgScript" this just prints the SQL statement with the variables replaced with values in the Messages window, but does not return the results itself.

Comment: Nvm, found the answer here: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/201001231852.35717.j.kobal@gmx.com Need to set the output to a variable and print it, so like this: `declare @mytbl, @maxid;
set @mytbl = 'sometable';
set @maxid = 2500;
set @res = select count(*) from @mytbl where id <= @maxid;
print @res;`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to create a view.

```
-- create view to store variable list
create view script_variables as select 'soifsdaofisd.gmail.com' as message_id;
-- run your script
select * from emails where message_id = (select message_id from script_variables);
-- clean up 
drop view script_variables;
```

Comment: This works really well and FAST!

Answer (score 0):

Try with bellow structure:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    a INT;
BEGIN
    a := 1;
END;
$$;
```