# PostgreSQL: SET equivalent to MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to insert the id of one table into another in PostgreSQL. First I want to select the id of table1 where it equals a specific value and store that into a variable. In MySQL I can do:

```
SET @last_id_in = (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE col1 = 1);
```

Then I can insert where the value would equal @last_id_in. How can I do something similar in PostgreSQL?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-postgresql.  With that said, given your first comment, you might not need the variable.  Depends on the rest of your sql.

Comment: Recent related answer about variables in Postgres: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561408/how-do-i-declare-variables-in-pgadmin/23771292#23771292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where you want your variable -- i.e. in a `PL/pgSQL` `function`, or in a script from which you're calling into Postgres...

`PL/pgSQL`, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE col1 = 1
RETURNING id INTO last_id_in;
```

where **last_id_in** is previously declared as `integer` (or whatever type **id** is).

Script:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT id FROM table1
WHERE col1 = 1
RETURNING id;
```

And then the `cursor` in whatever library you're interacting with `Postgres` with should contain that value for you to use elsewhere.

If the goal is simply to insert an element from one table into another, then the `script` version above can leave off the `RETURNING` clause, as there's no intervening steps.