# Get string after '/' character

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I want to extract the string after the character '/' in a PostgreSQL SELECT query.

The field name is `source_path`, table name is `movies_history`.

Data Examples:

Values for source_path:

- 184738/file1.mov
- 194839/file2.mov
- 183940/file3.mxf
- 118942/file4.mp4

And so forth. All the values for source_path are in this format

- random_number/filename.xxx

I need to get 'file.xxx' string only.

Comment: This sounds like a reason to use regex!  Are you processing the data at all after getting it, or do you only want filename.mov returned from the DB?  It's easier to do this sort of thing after you get the data back, but I think still possible to do it in SQL.

Comment: I will be processing the data after getting it.

Comment: How are you processing it when it's returned? PHP?  If so you can use a combination of http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php to find the last '/', and then http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php to get just the filename.

Comment: *one* example is hardly a sufficient description of what strings can look like. You need to be much more specific to get a useful query.

Comment: @ Erwin, I added more examples in case someone else has a similar question. Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If your case is that simple (*exactly* one `/` in the string) use [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

```
SELECT split_part(source_path, '/', 2) ...
```

**If** there can be *multiple* `/`, and you want the string after the *last* one, a simple and fast solution would be to process the string backwards with [`reverse()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), take the first part, and `reverse()` again:

```
SELECT reverse(split_part(reverse(source_path), '/', 1)) ...
```

**Or** you could use the more versatile (and more expensive) [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) with a regular expression:

```
SELECT substring(source_path, '[^/]*$') ...
```

Explanation:

`[...]` .. encloses a list of characters to form a character class.
`[^...]` .. if the list starts with `^` it's the *inversion* (all characters not in the list).
`*` .. quantifier for 0-n times.
`$` .. anchor to end of string.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=098fe4d061eddcb311ee7f2a16718692)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/4675)</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to store the returned substring values into a variable? Sorry for being a complete noob, but I am studying SQL and want to understand more.

Comment: Depends on the context and use case. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14261927/939860. Else, please ask a new *question*, comments are not the place.

Comment: Hi Erwin. I just return here because got one upvote. Your first solution is great because I think only one `/` on OP requirement. But when I try your second solution with multiple `/` return everything after the first `/` ... instead of the text after **last one** `/` not sure if that was the intent.  You can check difference here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9525

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Thanks for pointing out. The previous 2nd solution did not work for multiple `/` in the string. I replaced it with a solution that actually works. Updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9577

Answer (score 6):

You need use [*substring*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) function

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2989)

```
SELECT substring('1245487/filename.mov' from '%/#"%#"%' for '#');
```

Explanation:

```
%/
```

This mean `%` some text and then a `/`

```
#"%#"
```

each `#` is the place holder defined in the last part `for '#'` and need and aditional `"`

So you have `<placeholder> % <placeholder>` and function will return what is found inside both placeholder. In this case is `%` or the rest of the string after `/`

**FINAL QUERY:**

```
 SELECT substring(source_path from '%/#"%#"%' for '#');
 FROM movies_history
```

Comment: No problem, I include the final query. And I dont want be rude, but if you couldn't figure it out that last step, you may need a beginner sql course first.

Comment: Thanks I got it after posting it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the split_part string function,
`syntax: split_part(string,delimiter,position)`

- string example: exx = "2022-06-12"
  Note: can be "@ertl/eitd/record_4" etc
- delimiter: any character for the above example ("-" or "/")
- Position: nth position,
- How it works: the above exx string will be split in x times based on the delimiter
  e.g position 1- 2022, position 2-06, position 3-12
  so the nth position helps choose what you want to return
  thus based on your example:
  `syntax: slipt_part(random_number/filename.xxx,"/",2)`
  output: filename.xxx