# How to find text pattern in string for postgresql SQL

Tags: postgresql

For this sample string: "... Key Match extra text..."

How do I get the value "Match", which is the string between blank spaces after "Key"?

is there a better way than:
Find position of "Key "->pos1, find position of first blank space after p1 -> p2, substring(string,  p1,p2)?

This is not working as I expected

```
Select substring('Key Match extra text', 'Key (.+) ');
---
Match extra
```

Comment: No idea what is better in your case, but _perhaps_ [9.7. Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) has a list of options you may want to put into consideration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32381860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the regex be "non-greedy", so that `.+` matches as few as possible:

```
Select substring('Key Match extra text', 'Key (.+?) ');
```

Or you can change `.` to something that won't match spaces:

```
Select substring('Key Match extra text', 'Key (\S+) ');
```

Comment: The question mark did the trick. Thanks.