# Using script variables in sql-do session not works?

Tags: postgresql, session, variables

It is not a `psql` terminal, I can't  use `\set myvariable value` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588796/287948), and can't use ugly *set+current_setting()* [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261927/287948) ... I am using Pg9+ (9.5), so I think I can use  [sql-do](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) as [this in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325367/287948)... But not working.

```
DO $$
DECLARE foo int := bar('etc');
BEGIN
    SELECT run_somthing(foo,1);
    SELECT run_somthing(foo,2);
END
$$;
```

- ERROR-1: *"query has no destination for the resulting data   HINT: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM."*
- ERROR-2: (after add PERFORM) *"ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT""*.

---

NOTE:

Also sintax error when using function workaround

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION doThis() RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE 
    foo int := bar('etc');
BEGIN
    SELECT run_somthing(foo,1);  -- bug also with PERFORM clause
    SELECT run_somthing(foo,2);
    RETURN 1;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT doThis();
```

Comment: Which syntax errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry @JoachimIsaksson, I edited, adding errors.