# INSERT with dynamic column names

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, names

I have column names stored in variable `colls`, next I execute code:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
v_name text :=  quote_ident('colls');
BEGIN
EXECUTE 'insert into table1 select '|| colls ||' from table2 ';
-- EXECUTE 'insert into table1 select '|| v_name ||' from table2 ';
END$$;
```

I have got error: *column "colls" does not exist.* Program used `colls` as name not as variable. What am I doing wrong?

I have found similar example in documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. There'll be a solution. And always disclose your version of Postgres. I seriously doubt that you work with Postgres 8.1, even though you link to that version of the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have column names stored in variable `colls`

No, you don't. You have a variable `v_name` - which holds a *single* word: `'colls'`. About variables in SQL:

- [User defined variables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql/14261927#14261927)

Read the chapters [**Identifiers and Key Words**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) and [**Constants**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) in the manual.

And if you had *multiple* column names in a single variable, you could not use `quote_ident()` like that. It would escape the *whole* string as a single identifier.

---

I guess the basic misunderstanding is this: `'colls'` is a *string constant*, not a *variable*. There are no other variables in a `DO` statement than the ones you declare in the `DECLARE` section. You might be looking for ***a function that takes a variable number of column names as parameter(s)*** ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC _cols text[])
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT 'INSERT INTO table1 SELECT '
          || string_agg(quote_ident(col), ', ')
          || ' FROM table2'
      FROM   unnest(_cols) col
      );
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_insert_these_columns('abd', 'NeW Deal');          -- column names case sensitive!
SELECT f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC '{abd, NeW Deal}'); -- column names case sensitive!
```

Note how I unnest the array of column names and escape them *one by one*.
A `VARIADIC` parameter should be perfect for your use case. You can either pass a list of column names or an array.
Either way, be vary of SQL injection.
Related, with more explanation:

- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Comment: Thank you for information, I was looking for that solution. I have one more question related to this topic. I have array cols,  which contain names of columns.     array     --------------  {"name,age"} (1 row), how I can pass that array to f_insert_these_columns function? When I have tried select f_insert_these_columns(VARIADIC cols), I have got error there is no column name cols.

Comment: @user2706590: The syntax for an array literal with two elements (`'name'` and `'age'`) is `'{name,age}'`. What you display (`'{"name,age"}'`) is an array with a *single* element `'name,age'`.

Comment: When I have used syntax '{name, age}' it works, but I would like pass variable named cols to function. Something like f_insert_columns(VARIADIC cols). I corrected something and when I run select * from cols I get:    array    ------------ {name,age} (1 row) , but still i have got the same error after running f_insert_columns(VARIADIC cols). error: column cols does not exist.

Comment: @user2706590: Please start a new question to show the *exact* code and data you use; and your exact version of Postgres as well as the verbatim error message. The error message you display is not possible with the code I supplied.

Comment: Ok, I have posted new question with full code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907182/copy-records-with-dynamic-column-names