# Database Wide Constant

Tags: postgresql

I have several type columns in my database schema.

For example there is a `type_id` column which can either be the primary, secondary, work or old address.

Querying for all old addresses of an employee would look like this:

```
select a.*
from employees e
join employeeaddresses ea on ea.employee_id = e.employee_id
join addresses a on ea.adress_id = a.address_id
where ea.type_id = 4 -- old addresses
```

I would like to introduce a database wide constant `TYPE_OLDADDRESS` that is internally mapped to 4.

So the query would look like this:

```
select a.*
from employees e
join employeeaddresses ea on ea.employee_id = e.employee_id
join addresses a on ea.adress_id = a.address_id
where ea.type_id = TYPE_OLDADDRESS;
```

Is postgres capable of this or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I would use a function: `where ea.type_id = type_oldaddress()`

Comment: Some possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2):

You could to set/create the session/role/database wide parameters like:

```
set parameter.name to value; -- for the current session only
alter role rolename set parameter.name to value; -- for the specified role, relogin required
alter database dbname set parameter.name to value; -- for the specified database, relogin required
```

Then get it using `current_setting` function:

```
select current_setting('parameter.name');
```

The function returns the text value so the explicit type cast could be necessary.

To remove the parameter definition from the role/database use `reset` instead of `set` key word:

```
alter database dbname reset parameter.name;
```

The dot in the custom parameter name is required.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE global_constants(
   name char(20),
   value int);
```

insert the corresponding value

```
insert into global_constants values('TYPE_OLDADDRESS',4);
```

then you can use a subquery:

```
select a.*
from employees e
join employeeaddresses ea on ea.employee_id = e.employee_id
join addresses a on ea.adress_id = a.address_id
where ea.type_id = (select value from global contantants where name = 'TYPE_OLDADDRESS');
```

You could also use a UDF. It all depends on the syntax you prefer.