# How to use variable settings in trigger functions?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, global-variables, plpgsql

I would like to record the id of a user in the session/transaction, using `SET`, so I could be able to access it later in a trigger function, using `current_setting`. Basically, I'm trying option n2 from a [very similar ticket posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172524/passing-user-id-to-postgresql-triggers), with the difference that I'm using PG 10.1 .

I've been trying 3 approaches to setting the variable:

- `SET local myvars.user_id = 4`, thereby setting it locally in the transaction;
- `SET myvars.user_id = 4`, thereby setting it in the session;
- `SELECT set_config('myvars.user_id', '4', false)`, which depending of the last argument, will be a shortcut for the previous 2 options.

None of them is usable in the trigger, which receives `NULL` when getting the variable through `current_setting`. Here is a script I've devised to troubleshoot it (can be easily used with the postgres docker image):

```
database=$POSTGRES_DB
user=$POSTGRES_USER
[ -z "$user" ] && user="postgres"

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$user" $database <<-EOSQL
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS add_transition1 ON houses;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS houses (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(80),
        created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transitions1 (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        house_id INTEGER,
        user_id INTEGER,
        created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        FOREIGN KEY(house_id) REFERENCES houses (id) ON DELETE CASCADE

    );

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_transition1() RETURNS TRIGGER AS \$\$
        DECLARE
            user_id integer;
        BEGIN
            user_id := current_setting('myvars.user_id')::integer || NULL;
            INSERT INTO transitions1 (user_id, house_id) VALUES (user_id, NEW.id);
            RETURN NULL;
        END;
    \$\$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    CREATE TRIGGER add_transition1 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON houses FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_transition1();

    BEGIN;
    %1% SELECT current_setting('myvars.user_id');
    %2% SELECT set_config('myvars.user_id', '55', false);
    %3% SELECT current_setting('myvars.user_id');
    INSERT INTO houses (name) VALUES ('HOUSE PARTY') RETURNING houses.id;
    SELECT * from houses;
    SELECT * from transitions1;
    COMMIT;
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS add_transition1 ON houses;
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS add_transition1;
    DROP TABLE transitions1;
        DROP TABLE houses;
EOSQL
```

The conclusion I came to was that the function is triggered in a different transaction and a different (?) session. Is this something that one can configure, so that all happens within the same context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Handle all possible cases for the *[customized option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html)* properly:

1. option not set yet

All references to it raise an **exception**, including [`current_setting()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) unless called with the second parameter *`missing_ok`*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE)

> If there is no setting named *`setting_name`*, `current_setting` throws an error unless *`missing_ok`* is supplied and is `true`.

2. option set to a valid integer literal
3. option set to an invalid integer literal
4. option reset (which burns down to a special case of *3.*)

For instance, if you set a customized option with `SET LOCAL` or `set_config('myvars.user_id3', '55', true)`, the option value is reset at the end of the transaction. It still *exists*, can be referenced, but it returns an empty string now (`''`) - which cannot be cast to `integer`.

Obvious mistakes in your demo aside, you need to prepare for all 4 cases. So:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_transition1()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _user_id text := current_setting('myvars.user_id', true);  -- see 1.
BEGIN
   IF _user_id ~ '^\d+$' THEN  -- one or more digits?
      INSERT INTO transitions1 (user_id, house_id)
      VALUES (_user_id::int, NEW.id);  -- valid int, cast is safe
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO transitions1 (user_id, house_id)
      VALUES (null, NEW.id);           -- use null instead

      RAISE WARNING 'Invalid user_id % for house_id % was reset to null!'
                  , quote_literal(_user_id), NEW.id;  -- optional
   END IF;

   RETURN NULL;  -- OK for AFTER trigger
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6557b3c239efd23f1ae861747d27d347)*

Notes:

- Avoid variable names matching column names. Very error prone. One popular naming convention is to prepend variable names with an underscore: `_user_id`.
- Assign at declaration time to save another assignment. Note the data type `text`. We'll cast later, after sorting out invalid input.
- Avoid raising / trapping an exception *if possible*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

  > A block containing an `EXCEPTION` clause is significantly more expensive
  > to enter and exit than a block without one. Therefore, don't use
  > `EXCEPTION` without need.
- Test for valid integer strings. This simple regular expression allows only digits (no leading sign, no white space): `_user_id ~ '^\d+$'`. I reset to null for any invalid input. Adapt to your needs.
- I added an optional `WARNING` for your debugging convenience.
- Cases `3.` and `4.` only arise because customized options are string literals (type `text`), valid data types cannot be enforced automatically.

Related:

- [User defined variables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql/14261927#14261927)
- [Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query)

All that aside, there may be more elegant solutions for what you are trying to do without customized options, depending on your exact requirements. Maybe this:

- [Fastest way to get current user's OID in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56499/3684)

Comment: Your response was the most comprehensive of all, although I went with a variation of @garysieling 's response. But you touched on most of the important matters; in the beginning, `myvars.user_id` is NULL, after using `SET LOCAL` is it reset to `''` at transaction's end, and I have to account for all cases.

Answer (score 7):

It is not clear why you are trying to concat `NULL` to `user_id` but it is obviously the cause of the problem. Get rid of it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_transition1() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
        user_id integer;
    BEGIN
        user_id := current_setting('myvars.user_id')::integer;
        INSERT INTO transitions1 (user_id, house_id) VALUES (user_id, NEW.id);
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that

```
SELECT 55 || NULL
```

always gives `NULL`.

Comment: but how do I set up the equivalent? I'd like to get NULL back when the setting's not available.

Comment: @ChuckE `user_id := current_setting('myvars.user_id', true)::integer;`

Comment: @ChuckE PS: I have feeling that you are confusing SQL string concatenation operator `||` and C logical "or" operator `||`...

Answer (score 5):

You can catch the exception when the value doesn't exist - here's the changes I made to get this to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_transition1() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
        user_id integer;
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            user_id := current_setting('myvars.user_id')::integer;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            user_id := 0;
        END;

        INSERT INTO transitions1 (user_id, house_id) VALUES (user_id, NEW.id);
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_house() RETURNS void as $$
 DECLARE
    user_id integer;
 BEGIN 
   PERFORM set_config('myvars.user_id', '55', false);

   INSERT INTO houses (name) VALUES ('HOUSE PARTY');
 END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Although I haven't selected it, your example provided the blueprint for my final implementation. Thx a bunch!