# Defining global constants in Postgresql stored function/procedures?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, constants, global

I have a set of functions I have created in PostgreSql. I would like to be able to configure some behavior and limits with global constants.

So far, I have implemented functions like these, which my functions call to retrieve the constant value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION slice_length()
RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN 50;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

I was wondering, is there a better/smarter way to achieve this?

Comment: I personally like your approach, but ran into this question my self a few years back. This was the alternative that I found http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plperl-global.html.  I'm not sure it buys you anything, but it's an option. Along with the table approach below.

Comment: @JustKim That does not enforce data type constraints and a cast is needed on the function's returned text when the data is not text.

Comment: @JVerstry Also take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663599/creating-constant-string-for-a-postgres-entire-database. It looks like your approach may be the way to go.

Comment: @JustKim Nice finding. If you create an answer with a reference to the question, I'll approve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this other answer. It uses the same approach that you do.

[Create constant string for entire database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663599/creating-constant-string-for-a-postgres-entire-database)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem: store some sort of configuration and access it from my function.
To solve the problem I created a function which returns a constant JSONB containing my configuration.

The function looks like this:

```
create or replace function config()
    returns jsonb
    language plpgsql
    immutable 
as $BODY$

declare
job_manager_config constant jsonb := '{

    "notify": {
        
        "channels": {
            "all_available": "all.available",
            "all_status": "all.status",
            "task_available": "task.%s.available",
            "task_status": "task.%s.status",
            "job": "job.%s"
        },

    }

    "allowed_pets": {
        "dogs": 6,
        "cats": 6,
        "rabbits": 3,
        "lions": 2,
        "sweet_piranha": 8
    }

}';

begin
    return job_manager_config;
end;
$BODY$;
```

To access configuration elements quickly I defined a second function to query the configuration. This function accepts a path as a list of strings and return the value (or JSON object) found at the path.
Note that the **returned value is text but you can easily cast it to the actual type**.

```
create or replace function job_manager.config(
    variadic path_array text[])
    returns text
    language plpgsql
    immutable 
as $BODY$

begin
    -- Return selected object as text (instead of json or jsonb)
    return jsonb_extract_path_text(job_manager.config(), variadic path_array);
end;

$BODY$;
```

This is a usage example:

```
test=# select job_manager.config('notify', 'channels', 'job');
       config       
--------------------
 job_manager.job.%s
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a table for that:

```
create table constant (c1 int, c2 numeric);
insert into constant (c1, c2) values (100, 33.2);
```

The function, SQL not PL/pgSQL, would retrieve the single row:

```
create or replace function get_constants()
returns constant as $$
    select *
    from constant;
$$ language sql immutable;
```

And would be called for each constant:

```
select (get_constants()).c1, (get_constants()).c2;
```

All data would be in a single place and retrieved with a single function.

If a table is really that bad then place all the values in a single function:

```
create or replace function get_constants (
    c1 out int, c2 out numeric
) returns record as $$
    select 100, 33.5;
$$ language sql immutable;
```

And use it as above.

Comment: Ok, but how is that better than an immutable function?

Comment: I'd be interested to see why a table is better. Wouldn't that table become "hot"?

Comment: @Just I'm declaring the function [`immutable`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)

Comment: @Just If by _hot_ you mean updateable by the users then the adequate permissions should be set.

Comment: I just mean if you have a system with 500 users and you make use of this table heavily it will have lots of io against it. Be it reads or writes. Don't get me wrong I like the approach I have just been guided away from this type of approach in the past by people with more weight than me, and I had to figure an other solution out. I never had the chance to test the "hottness" factor.

Comment: @JustKim See if you like the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a table named `constants` for that purpose as mentioned [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22613917/9035706) where each column corresponds to one setting.

To ensure that no more than one row can be added to the table, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25393923/9035706) might be helpful.

As come comments have pointed to the increased I/O when constants are stored like this as opposed to storing constants as functions, [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/postgresql-force-data-into-memory) might be a good reeding.