# Create constant string for entire database

Tags: sql, postgresql, constants

I'm still new to SQL, so I'm having some little issues to solve.
I'm running a Postgres database in Acqua Data Studio, with some queries that get follow the same model.
Some variables into these queries are the same, but may change in the future...

Thinking of an optimized database, it would be faster to change the value of a constant than to enter on 20+ queries and change the same aspect in all of them.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table AS Default_Configs      
    LEFT JOIN Table AS Test_Configs
        ON Default_Configs.Column1 = 'BLABLABLA'
```

Imagining 'BLABLABLA' could be 'XXX', how could I make 'BLABLABLA' a constant to every View that is created following this pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a tiny function that serves as "global constant":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_my_constant()
  RETURNS text AS
$$SELECT text 'XXX'$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE; -- see below
```

And use that function instead of `'BLABLABLA'` in your queries.

Be sure to declare the data type correctly and make the [function `IMMUTABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) (because it is) for better performance with big queries.

In Postgres 9.6 or later add `PARALLEL SAFE`, so it won't block parallel query plans. The setting isn't valid in older versions.

To change the constant, replace the function by running an updated `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` statement. Invalidates query plans using it automatically, so queries are re-planned. Should be safe for concurrent use. Transactions starting after the change use the new function. But indexes involving the function have to be rebuilt manually.

---

Alternatively (especially in pg 9.2 or later), you could set a [Customized Option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) as "global constant" for the whole cluster, a given DB, a given role etc, and retrieve the value with:

```
current_setting('constant.blabla')
```

One limitation: the value is always `text` and may have to be cast to a target type.

Related:

- [User defined variables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261035/user-defined-variables-in-postgresql/14261927#14261927)

Many ways to set it:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Comment: Thank for the info! Instead of 'BLABLABLA' i would only use f_my_constant?

Comment: @ZeldaElf `f_my_constant()`, including the parens.

Comment: I just wrote a microbenchmark to test the difference in performance between an immutable function and a single-row/single-column table -- I was very surprised that the table outperformed the function in multiple runs. I hope to write it up as a question here at SO but I would caution against the accepted wisdom. With functions you also have to change the value with DDL rather than DML, which has a couple of negative implications.

Comment: All true and to be expected. A function has more overhead than reading the value from a singleton table. The difference is tiny, though, especially if the function can be inlined. Since Postgres 9.2 a customized option would be another good alternative. I added pointers above.