# How to allow only one row for a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have one table in which I would like **only one entry**. So if someone is trying to insert another row it shouldn't be allowed, only after someone deleted the previously existing row.

How do I set a rule for a table like this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A `UNIQUE` constraint allows multiple rows with `null` values, because two `null` values are not considered to be the same. (Except when using [`NULLS NOT DISTINCT` in Postgres 15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/939860) or later.)

Similar considerations apply to `CHECK` constraints. They allow the expression to be `true` or `null` (just not `false`). Again, `null` values get past the check.

To rule that out, define  the column `NOT NULL`. Or make it the `PRIMARY KEY` since PK columns are defined `NOT NULL` automatically. See:

- [Why can I create a table with PRIMARY KEY on a nullable column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006374/why-can-i-create-a-table-with-primary-key-on-a-nullable-column/20006502#20006502)

Also, just use `boolean`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.onerow (
   onerow_id bool PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT true
 , data text
 , CONSTRAINT onerow_uni CHECK (onerow_id)
);
```

The `CHECK` constraint can be that simple for a `boolean` column. Only `true` is allowed.

You may want to [`REVOKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) (or not `GRANT`) the `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE` privileges from `public` (and all other roles) to prevent the single row from ever being deleted. Like:

```
REVOKE DELETE, TRUNCATE ON public.onerow FROM public;
```

Answer (score 16):

Add a new column to the table, then add a check constraint and a uniqueness constraint on this column.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE logging (
    LogId integer UNIQUE default(1),
    MyData text,
    OtherStuff numeric,
    Constraint CHK_Logging_singlerow CHECK (LogId = 1)
);
```

Now you can only ever have one row with a LogId = 1.  If you try to add a new row it will either break the uniqueness or check constraint.

(I might have messed up the syntax, but it gives you an idea?)

Comment: `UNIQUE` constraints allow (multiple) `NULL` values, so this is *not safe*. Details in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I checked this and PostgreSQL works differently to SQL Server; SQL Server would only allow a single NULL value (which in my opinion is a much more sensible implementation).  Anyway, this is all irrelevant as the idea is to NOT specify LogId when creating a new row, which will set the value to the default of 1, which isn't NULL so it doesn't really matter?  However, if we are being VERY pedantic, I guess the definition should be NOT NULL :P

Comment: There are two kind of DB admins: the "pedantic" ones and the ones posting desperate questions about mysteriously "broken" databases on SO. :p

Answer (score 7):

You should create a `ON BEFORE INSERT` trigger on this table. On the trigger, call a procedure that checks `count(*)`  and when the count is 1, it returns an exception message to the user otherwise the insert is allowed to proceed.

Check [this documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) for an example.

Comment: Possible, but much more expensive and complicated than necessary.

Comment: Your way works, no doubt, and yes, this is more expensive. I was simply offering a solution that works without altering the table.

Comment: Why would the expensiveness of this matter when this isn't a table you're going to be inserting to, ever (beyond the one time; presumably the purpose of such a table is to store a singleton like configuration)? Aesthetically it's certainly much more pleasant to me because you don't need columns and checks that aren't related to the data being stored.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose no additional field is requried here. Just unique index on constant:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_onerow ON onerow ((0));
```

Comment: It's really nice way to do it, but if you need do something `ON CONFLICT` (for example, upsert), then you'll have to use an artificial column.

Answer (score 4):

You can force single row with:

```
id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (1) STORED UNIQUE
```

This will force the `id` column to always be `1` and since it's a `UNIQUE` column the table will only be able to hold this row.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8ZjmdRHY5gEPSQ7Vobuzoa/0)