# PostgreSQL: how to get & set an enumerated list variable in a script?

Tags: postgresql

I am using GUC style variables in an SQL script like this:

```
set mycustom.var = 5;
select current_setting('mycustom.var');
```

that works fine for strings and integers... but how do I get and set enumerated lists of integers?

Ideally, I'd like to populated the enumerated list with random unique values using this code:

```
SELECT   num
FROM     GENERATE_SERIES (1, 10) AS s(num)
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT    6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html)

```
select set_config(
    'mycustom.list', 
    (
        select array_agg(num)::text
        from (
            select num
            from generate_series (1, 10) as s(num)
            order by random()
            limit 6
        ) s
    ),
    false
);
```

Of course, the setting is of type text:

```
select current_setting('mycustom.list', true);

 current_setting
-----------------
 {2,6,1,3,10,8}
(1 row)
```

However, you can easily convert it to set of rows:

```
select * 
from unnest(current_setting('mycustom.list', true)::int[])

 unnest
--------
      2
      6
      1
      3
     10
      8
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem to overcome: [`SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) expects **literal input**. You can't feed the result of a query to it directly.

One way around it: dynamic SQL like:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
      'SET mycustom.var = %L'
     , ARRAY(
         SELECT *
         FROM   generate_series(1, 10) 
         ORDER  BY random()
         LIMIT  6
         )::text
      );
END
$$;
```

Or use [`set_config()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html):

```
SELECT set_config('mycustom.var'
                , ARRAY(
                     SELECT *
                     FROM   generate_series(1, 10) 
                     ORDER  BY random()
                     LIMIT  6
                     )::text
                , false);
```

Then:

```
SELECT current_setting('mycustom.var')::int[];
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=83d8284d7b827aedf0bdf57663ebc512)*

This returns an array of integer: `int[]`.

A temporary function would be an alternative. Possibly with a built-in *dynamic* result (while this solution only stores the result, immutably):

- [Is there a way to define a named constant in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316773/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-named-constant-in-a-postgresql-query/13317628#13317628)

Comment: hmm, I get 2 errors:   [Code: , SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEGIN"  Position: 4

[Code: , SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
  Position: 7

Comment: Works for me, I tested with Postgres 11. See the added fiddle.

Comment: This returns an array of integer: `int[]`. Do you need an actual *list*? If so, in what form and data type exactly? In case you are running an outdated version of Postgres, you need to declare that.