# Declare interdependent constants in PostgreSQL to use all around the database

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am new to databases but I have a programming background.

I want to declare constants as I would in any programming language like this, as an idea.

```
MY_CONSTANT1 = 5
MY_CONSTANT2 = MY_CONSTANT1 * 20
MY_CONSTANT3 = 'insert regex capture group here'
MY_CONSTANT4 = 'insert regex capture group here'
MY_CONSTANT5 = '(' || MY_CONSTANT3 || '|' || MY_CONSTANT4 || ')'
```

The constants depend on eachother and are calculated with eachother. This is absolutely necessary for the scenario where for example I want to use it all around the database as for example saved regex groups, or mathematical constants, or in general data that doesn't change often and is calculated interdependantly. If you have a programming background like me you'd know why this is crucial.

So far I have used this quick ugly bandage fix of a function, with the hopes of the immutable volatility to atleast inspire some optimizations to the compiler.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION util.get_text_constant(IN p_constant_name text)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    IMMUTABLE
    PARALLEL UNSAFE
    COST 100
    
AS $BODY$
declare
    v_constants jsonb := '{}';
begin
    v_constants := v_constants || jsonb_build_object(
        'RE_GROUP_NAME', '([A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)*( (?=[a-zA-Z])M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))?(?<! I))',
        'RE_GROUP_PHONE', '(07[0-9]{8}|\+(?!40)[0-9]{7,15})',
        'RE_GROUP_CODE', '(P[1-9][0-9]{4})',
        'RE_GROUP_LINK', '(https://[-a-zA-Z0-9\./\?\=\|\%]+)',
        'RE_GROUP_NICKNAME', '([0-9A-Z][0-9a-z]+( [0-9A-Z][0-9a-z]+)*)',
        
        'RE_GROUP_PARAGRAPH', '((?![[:space:]])[^\n]+(?<![[:space:]]))',
        
        'RE_GROUP_NUMBER', '((0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}( [0-9]{3})*)(\.[0-9]+)?(K|M)?)',
        
        'VAT_STANDARD', '0.19'
    );
    if v_constants ? p_constant_name then
        return v_constants ->> p_constant_name;
    end if;
    
    v_constants := v_constants || jsonb_build_object(
        'RE_GROUP_COUNTERVALUE', '(' || util.get_text_constant('RE_GROUP_NUMBER') || '(\%| FIX)( \+ TVA)?)',
        'RE_GROUP_IDENTIFICATOR',
        ('('
            || 'I - ' || util.get_text_constant('RE_GROUP_CODE')
            || '|I - ' || util.get_text_constant('RE_GROUP_LINK')
            || '|(C|I) - ' || util.get_text_constant('RE_GROUP_PHONE')
            || '|(C|I) - ' || util.get_text_constant('RE_GROUP_NAME')
            || '|(C|I) - ' || util.get_text_constant('RE_GROUP_NAME') || ' - ' || util.get_text_constant('RE_GROUP_NICKNAME')
        || ')')
    );
    if v_constants ? p_constant_name then
        return v_constants ->> p_constant_name;
    end if;
    
    raise exception 'Constant does not exist "%"', p_constant_name;
end
$BODY$;
```

The main problems with it are that it only supports text type and that, obviously, it gets really ugly really quick because I have to add a new section of code for every layer of intedependence.

I cannot rely on tables either because I have to use these constants, literally as constants, like in type definitions and other immutable functions for example.

```
CREATE DOMAIN util.phone_text AS text
    CONSTRAINT phone_text_check1 CHECK ((VALUE ~ util.unique_trimmed_group(util.text_constants('RE_GROUP_PHONE'::text))));


ALTER DOMAIN util.phone_text OWNER TO postgres;
```

Seeing that after all this time a database system as advanced as PostgreSQL hasn't developed a database-wide interdependent constants functionality means that there is something deeply wrong with my approach. So how would you guys do it, or go about it?

EDIT: [This answer helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317628/9518460)

Comment: Why can't you rely on tables? You might have records that never change, other records change just once in a decade and others more often. For example your constant VAT_STANDARD is not that constant, I have seen a few changes for that value. And sure, I do understand that these values should not be changed by everybody, that's why you use GRANT and REVOKE in combination with different roles. Another option is to create a view containing one json that has all the constants.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thank you for your comment. Am I going to be able to use them in type definitions or checks even if I put them in a table? And even in that case how can I make them interdependent?

Answer (score 0):

I realised on my own one option could be to declare a `constants` schema and inside it declare one immutable "get" function for each constant. This is the most clean and modular way I could possibly think of.

`get_vat_standard() -> returns 0.19`

`get_re_group_countervalue() -> returns '(' || get_re_group_number() || '(\%| FIX)( \+ TVA)?)'`

- This solves the problem of the type. Now I can return any type I want.
- This solves the problem of the code becoming uglier and uglier. I can return anything, and it evaluates cleanly. I don't need to change anything in the code no matter how many layer of interdependence I have.

As a nice added bonus this is also very modular because I can at any time change the return value to any expression, and even make the function not be immutable anymore to get the expression from another place.

Comment: *Now I can return any type I want.* and *...because I can at any time change the return value to any expression*  don't inspire confidence that this *I don't need to change anything in the code no matter how many layer of interdependence I have.* will work.

Comment: You assert *"[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317628/939860) did not help*", but your answer implements functions just like I advised over there. Kind of a contradiction.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You're right. I'm sorry I had the bad habit of only looking at the first answer. I'm going to edit my post now and upvote your answer.