# Divide two counts from one select

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, percentage

I have a table like this:

```
date(timestamp) Error(integer)   someOtherColumns
```

I have a query to select all the rows for specific date:

```
SELECT * from table
WHERE date::date = '2010-01-17'
```

Now I need to count all rows which Error is equal to 0(from that day) and divide it by count of all rows(from that day).

So result should look like this

```
Date(timestamp)      Percentage of failure
2010-01-17           0.30
```

Database is pretty big, millions of rows..

And it would be great if someone know how to do this for more days - interval from one day to another.

```
Date(timestamp)      Percentage of failure
2010-01-17           0.30
2010-01-18           0.71
and so on
```

Comment: BTW Do not use reserved words like `date` for column names. It can cause some nasty bugs in queries.

Comment: Can `error` be `NULL`? Do you need a row in the result for days with no entry in the table at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about this (if `error` could be only 1 and 0):

```
select
   date,
   sum(Error)::numeric / count(Error) as "Percentage of failure"
from Table1
group by date
```

or, if `error` could be any integer:

```
select
   date,
   sum(case when Error > 0 then 1 end)::numeric / count(Error) as "Percentage of failure"
from Table1
group by date
```

---

Just fount that I've counted `not 0` (assumed that error is when Error != 0), and didn't take nulls into accounts (don't know how do you want to treat it). So here's another query which treats nulls as 0 and counts percentage of failure in two opposite ways:

```
select
    date,
    round(count(nullif(Error, 0)) / count(*) ::numeric , 2) as "Percentage of failure",
    1- round(count(nullif(Error, 0)) / count(*) ::numeric , 2) as "Percentage of failure2"
from Table1
group by date
order by date;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a08ef/10)</kbd>**

Comment: @Roman Pekar: This will (or at least should) fail with division by 0 if count(*) is 0...

Comment: @Quandary well.. don't think any SQL query could return record with count(*) = 0 :)

Comment: @Roman Pekar: Ah yea,  my fault, you're right, group by saves you there by just omiting the days of no activity.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
select cast(data1.count1 as float)/ cast(data2.count2 as float) 
 from (
select count(*) as count1 from table date::date = '2010-01-17' and Error = 0) data1, 

(select count(*) as count1 from table date::date = '2010-01-17') data2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date
     , round(count((error = 0) OR NULL) / count(*)::numeric, 2) AS percent_fail
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

This even works if `error` can be `NULL`.

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/52b9e/2)

Much more (incl. implications on performance) under this closely related question:
[Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897)

Comparison and benchmark of ways to count in [this related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572).

Comment: @quin61: Be sure to follow the links for information on performance. `count(*)` is a bit faster than `count(col)` and also safe against NULL values. Strictly speaking, Roman's answer is incorrect as long we don't know whether the column can be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generate_series and takes it from there.

Like this:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
     SELECT 
         m
        --,extract('year'  FROM m) AS theyear
        --,extract('month' FROM m) AS themonth
        --,extract('day' FROM m) AS theday

        ,(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM  table WHERE date::date = m AND Error = 1) AS data1 
        ,(SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM  table WHERE date::date = m) AS data2 
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT generate_series('2012-04-01'::date, '2016-01-01'::date, interval '1 day') AS m
    ) AS g 
) -- END OF CTE 

SELECT 
      m
     ,COALESCE(data1 * 100.0 / NULLIF(data2, 0.0), 0.0) AS ErrorPercentage
FROM CTE
```

See this for details: 
[How to perform a select query in a DO block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652477/postgresql-how-to-perform-a-select-query-in-a-do-block)

Comment: It's still giving me: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: WITH CTE AS

Comment: @quin61: I don't know what your table and date field is, maybe a invalid date, but that statement works fine on my machine.