# Return record with column definition from a function

Tags: postgresql, return-value, record, user-defined-functions, plpgsql

I know that Postgres allows to return a predefined composite datatype, a record and a table with column definition.

However I did not manage to return a simple record with defined columns so I always use tables even if I know that this will only return one line.

So my function definition looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name(p_param1 text, p_param2 json)
    RETURNS TABLE(
       col1    bigint,
       col2    integer,
       col3    integer
    )
```

If I try do return a record the same way it fails:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name(p_param1 text, p_param2 json)
    RETURNS RECORD(
       col1    bigint,
       col2    integer,
       col3    integer
    )
```

Is this not possible in Postgres?
I know that I can just declare a custom composite data type but I don't want to declare a type for every function returning a record.

Comment: What about using OUT parameters? Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `OUT` parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name(
        p_param1 text
  ,     p_param2 json
  , OUT col1 bigint
  , OUT col2 integer
  , OUT col3 integer)
  RETURNS record AS ...
```

The difference: this form returns exactly one row, while `RETURNS TABLE` returns 0-n rows.
More:

- [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)

Comment: thank you very much!!! its strange syntax to me but it does exactly what i was looking for!!