# What isolation level should I use for workers pulling from a queue of jobs to run?

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, concurrency, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I have a PostgreSQL database (v9.5.3) that's hosting "jobs" for workers to pull, run, and commit back.

When a worker wants a job, it runs something to the effect of:

```
SELECT MIN(sim_id) FROM job WHERE job_status = 0;
-- status 0 indicates it's ready to be run
```

`job` is a table with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE commit_schema.job (
  sim_id serial NOT NULL,
  controller_id smallint NOT NULL,
  controller_parameters smallint NOT NULL,
  model_id smallint NOT NULL,
  model_parameters smallint NOT NULL,
  client_id smallint,
  job_status smallint DEFAULT 0,
  initial_glucose_id smallint NOT NULL
);
```

Afterwards, it uses this `sim_id` to piece together a bunch of parameters in a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.par1, b.par2 FROM
a INNER JOIN b ON a.sim_id = b.sim_id;
```

These parameters are then return to the worker, along with the `sim_id`, and the job is run. The `sim_id` is locked by setting `job.job_status` to 1, using an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE job SET job_status = 1 WHERE sim_id = $1;
```

The results are then committed using that same `sim_id`.

Ideally,

1. Workers wouldn't under any circumstances be able to get the same `sim_id`.
2. Two workers requesting a job won't error out, one will just have to wait to receive a job.

I think that using a serializable isolation level will ensure that the `MIN()` always returns unique `sim_id`'s, but I believe this may also be achievable using a read committed isolation level. Then again, `MIN()` may not be able to concurrently and deterministically give unique `sim_id`'s to two concurrent workers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just fine for concurrent access using the default isolation level [Read Committed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) and [`FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) (new in pg 9.5):

```
UPDATE commit_schema.job j
SET    job_status = 1
FROM  (
   SELECT sim_id
   FROM   commit_schema.job
   WHERE  job_status = 0
   ORDER  BY sim_id
   LIMIT  1
   FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
   ) sub
WHERE  j.sim_id = sub.sim_id
RETURNING sim_id;
```

`job_status` should probably be defined `NOT NULL`.

Be wary of certain corner cases - detailed explanation in this related answer on dba.SE:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497)

#### To address [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709432/what-isolation-level-should-i-use-for-workers-pulling-from-a-queue-of-jobs-to-ru/38709971?noredirect=1#comment64878201_38709971)

There are various ways to return from a function:

- Make it a simple SQL function instead of PL/pgSQL.
- Or use [`RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN62587) with PL/pgSQL.
- Or assign the result to a variable with [`RETURNING ... INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) - which can be an `OUT` parameter, so it will be returned at the end of the function automatically. Or any other variable and return it explicitly.

Related (with code examples):

- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable/8169928#8169928)
- [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)

Comment: Quick question, does this "Returning" let me place this in a function? If my other functions are in plpgsql and expecting a table from the function that performs this, can this just be added as another column via the OUT clause in the declaration? Would it be something like `RETURNING sub.sim_id INTO function_sim_id`? Also in the event that there are no more jobs, what would happen?

Comment: @ijustlovemath: Yes. Consider the addendum.

Comment: One final question, if there are no more rows with job_status_id = 0, can I simply do an "IF sim_id IS NULL THEN foo()" after the UPDATE to handle that gracefully? Or is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: @ijustlovemath: I suggest `IF NOT FOUND THEN foo(); END IF;` in plpgsql code. Also consider details in the last chapter of [the linked answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1/69497#69497).