# Return a composite type or multiple columns from a PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, plpgsql, return-type

My aim is to write a function that takes in one parameter and returns two values. The query is working perfectly, however, when executed via the function made, I receive an error that a subquery should not return multiple columns.

My function is as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE double_integer_type AS (p1 integer, p2 integer);

DROP FUNCTION next_dvd_in_queue;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_dvd_in_queue (member_id_p1 integer) RETURNS double_integer_type as $$
BEGIN
RETURN(
    select temp2.dvdid,
       temp2.movie_title
from
    (select temp1.dvdid,
            temp1.movie_title,
            temp1.customer_priority
     from
         (select *
          from rentalqueue
          where rentalqueue.memberid=member_id_p1) temp1
     inner join dvd on dvd.dvdid=temp1.dvdid
     where dvd.dvdquantityonhand>0) temp2
order by temp2.customer_priority asc
limit 1
);
END; $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Call:

```
select dvdid from next_dvd_in_queue(3);
```

The query, when executed with a hard-coded value, is:

```
select temp2.dvdid,
       temp2.movie_title
from
    (select temp1.dvdid,
            temp1.movie_title,
            temp1.customer_priority
     from
         (select *
          from rentalqueue
          where rentalqueue.memberid=3) temp1
     inner join dvd on dvd.dvdid=temp1.dvdid
     where dvd.dvdquantityonhand>0) temp2
order by temp2.customer_priority asc
limit 1
```

The above query works fine.

However, when I call the function in the following way:

```
select * from next_dvd_in_queue(3);
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
> LINE 1: SELECT (
>                ^
> QUERY:  SELECT (
>     select temp2.dvdid,
>        temp2.movie_title
> from
>     (select temp1.dvdid,
>             temp1.movie_title,
>             temp1.customer_priority
>      from
>          (select *
>           from rentalqueue
>           where rentalqueue.memberid=3) temp1
>      inner join dvd on dvd.dvdid=temp1.dvdid
>      where dvd.dvdquantityonhand>0) temp2
> order by temp2.customer_priority asc
> limit 1
> )
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function next_dvd_in_queue(integer) line 3 at RETURN
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the syntax error with an explicit cast to the composite type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_dvd_in_queue (member_id_p1 integer)
  RETURNS double_integer_type AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN (
       SELECT ROW(temp2.dvdid, temp2.movie_title)::double_integer_type
       FROM  ...
   );
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

But I would remove the needless complication with the composite type and use **`OUT` parameters** instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.next_dvd_in_queue (member_id_p1 integer
                                                  OUT p1 integer
                                                  OUT p2 varchar(100)) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO p1, p2
          temp2.dvdid, temp2.movie_title
   FROM  ...

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Avoid naming collisions between parameter names and column names. I like to stick to a naming convention where I prefix all parameter names with `_`, so `_member_id_p1`, `_p1`, `_p2`.

Related:

- [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)
- [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)