# Generate JSON object from a dynamic set of input functions

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to write a function (f_all) that basically just calls other "partial" functions (e.g. `f_1`,`f_2`,`f_3`) and merges the results of them into one final JSON object. Function `f_all` will take a string array (e.g '1,2,3') and for every number in the array, it will add corresponding key in the resulting JSON , e.g. "part1" and value, which will be a result of the "partial" function.
So for example, for f_all('1,2,3') it should return JSON:

```
{"part1": {<result of f_1>},
 "part2": {<result of f_2>},
 "part3": {<result of f_3>}
}
```

I managed to achieve something similar using a `FOR` loop to append the result of each "partial" function to resulting array with `array_append()`. However, I need the result to be a simple JSON/JSONB object, not an array of objects.

This works and returns an array of json objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_all(ingeom geometry, parts text)
 RETURNS jsonb []
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE 
    arr TEXT ARRAY;
    i text;
    json_partx jsonb;
    resultjson_part jsonb;
    resultjson jsonb;
    resultarray json [];
 BEGIN
    arr = string_to_array(parts, ',');
    
    FOREACH i in ARRAY arr
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT f_' || i || '($1)' into json_partx using ingeom;
        resultjson_part = json_build_object('part' || i, json_partx);
        resultjson =  array_append(resultjson, resultjson_part);
    END LOOP;
        
    RETURN (resultjson);
END;
$function$;
```

In a similar manner, I want, in each loop iteration, to append key and value pairs into JSON object and return the resulting object.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> Function f_all will take a string array (e.g `'1,2,3'`)

But that's not an **array**. It's a list of values passed as plain text. Pass an actual array instead. Better yet, use a `VARIADIC` function so you can pass an array *or* a list of values.

Your function is open to **SQL injection**, which is a big no-go.

Also worth mentioning that the data type `geometry` used here requires the additional module [PostGis](https://postgis.net/) installed.

Assuming all your functions `f_1()` ... `f_N()` return a scalar result (not a set!), consider this radically simpler, faster and safer function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_all(_ingeom geometry, VARIADIC _parts int[], OUT _result jsonb)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF _parts <> '{}' THEN  -- rule out NULL and empty array as input
      EXECUTE 'SELECT to_jsonb(t.*) FROM (SELECT f_' || array_to_string(_parts, '($1), f_')
                                                     || '($1)) AS t(part'
                                                     || array_to_string(_parts, ', part') || ')'
      INTO  _result
      USING _ingeom;
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Parameter "_parts" must not be empty or NULL!';
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Returns a JSON object (as `jsonb`) as requested.

Call:

```
SELECT f_all('foo', 1, 2, 3);
```

Or:

```
SELECT f_all('foo', VARIADIC '{1,2,3}');
```

The function takes `integer` input, which rules out SQL injection a priori.

Using a subselect to conveniently build the JSON object. Alternatively, you could use [`jsonb_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) or [`jsonb_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE). See:

- [Return multiple columns of the same row as JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486784/return-multiple-columns-of-the-same-row-as-json-array-of-objects/26486910#26486910)

Using a `VARIADIC` function for convenience. See:

- [Pass multiple values in single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560)
- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

Using an `OUT` parameter for convenience. See:

- [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)
- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable/8169928#8169928)

---

To address your original (now void) question: use the [concatenation operator `||`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to "append" JSON objects:

```
SELECT jsonb '{"foo":1}' || jsonb '{"bar":"baz"}';
```