# Function in PostgreSQL returns null with "out" value

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jpa

I'm using a Java EE to do some queries and check how they work with PostgreSQL functions, but its always returns null when the parameter type is "out".

```
create function updateStudent (inout studentId int, out studentName varchar(15))
language plpgsql as $$
    begin
        select name into studentName from students where id = studentId;
        update students set name = studentName where id = studentId;
    end;
$$
```

```java
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("studentUnit");

        EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        StoredProcedureQuery query = manager
                .createStoredProcedureQuery("updateStudent");
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("studentId", Integer.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("studentName", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        query.setParameter("studentId", 1);
        query.execute();
        System.out.println(query.getOutputParameterValue("studentName"));
        manager.getTransaction().commit();

        emf.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The PL/pgSQL function should work (though the update is nonsense). Since it returns a record, call it with `SELECT * FROM updateStudent(1)` to get individual fields, not `SELECT updateStudent(1)`. Also, why return `studentId`? Would be simpler just returning the single field `studentName`.

Comment: @nbk: You are misreading the docs. Postgres functions can have `OUT` parameters. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20763195/939860