# Creating an anonymous DO block

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-cursor

Following Sergey's example here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60834163/1513027
I'm trying to create an anonymous DO block rather than a function.

If I have the FETCH inside the block, it gives a syntax error, possibly wanting an INTO clause.
And it doesn't matter whether the name of the cursor is in quotes.

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE  _query TEXT;
DECLARE  _cursor CONSTANT refcursor := _cursor;

BEGIN
   _query := 'select "Port", "Version", "AddDate" from "LatestLogEntry";';

   OPEN _cursor FOR EXECUTE _query;

   FETCH ALL FROM _cursor;   -- syntax error at ;
END
$$;
```

If I have it outside, as in Sergey's example, then it can't see the cursor declared inside the block. And it *does* matter whether the name of the cursor is in quotes.

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE  _query TEXT;
DECLARE  _cursor CONSTANT refcursor := '_cursor';

BEGIN
   _query := 'select "Port", "Version", "AddDate" from "LatestLogEntry";';

   OPEN _cursor FOR EXECUTE _query;
END
$$;

FETCH ALL FROM _cursor -- ERROR:  cursor "_cursor" does not exist
```

Comment: Your second example seems to work fine. https://dbfiddle.uk/iR50ki5o

Comment: where do you run the code in pgadmin it works and with postgres 15

Comment: @EdmCoff  Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: Note that `DECLARE` starts a _block_ where all variables can be defined. There is no need to start a new block for each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pgadmin this does work see screen below run postgres 15

as Sergey pointed out this has to be in a transaction, else you get the error message you get.

[image]

you can try to use it in an tranction

Comment: And there it is, right there in the original.  "Cursors are visible in the transaction scope so you should use this within one transaction."

Answer (score 1):

The answer was hidden in a comment in one of the examples.
-- need to be in a transaction to use cursors.
Wrapping it in a transaction works.

```
BEGIN;
DO 
$$
DECLARE  _query TEXT;
DECLARE  _cursor CONSTANT refcursor := '_cursor';

BEGIN
   _query := 'select "Port", "Version", "AddDate" from "LatestLogEntry";';

   OPEN _cursor FOR EXECUTE _query;
END
$$;

FETCH ALL FROM _cursor -- ERROR:  cursor "_cursor" does not exist

COMMIT
```