# New to Postgres. Can you help me with a couple simple statments?

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I'm very familiar with MSSQL but I need to work with some postgres stuff today. The end goal is to return the new id of a table for use elsewhere but since I'm unfamiliar with the syntax of postgress, I seem to be having some trouble.

**Problem 1:**

in MSSQL I would:

```
delcare @test_number int
select @test_number = 42
print @test_number
```

in Postgres I'm trying:

```
test_number integer;
test_number := 42
print test_number
```

but it doesnt like the first line:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "test_number"
LINE 1: test_number integer;
```

If I can figure this out, I think I've got my **real** problem solved which would be to do something like:

**Problem 2:**

in MSSQL I would:

```
declare @new_id int
insert into some_table (data1. data2)
select @new_id = @@identity
-- now use @new_id for w/e you want
```

in Postgres I'm trying:

```
new__id integer;
new_id := insert into some_table (data1, data2) returning id;
-- now use new_id for w/e you want
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on Google gives the following answer.

[How do you use variables in a simple PostgreSQL script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766657/how-do-you-use-variables-in-a-simple-postgresql-script#6990059)

It looks like you basically declare an anonymous inline pgsql function in your query. Also looks like it's new to Postgres 9.

Comment: what did you use a for search criteria? Also I googled postgres variables and found postgres docs that looked nothing like the syntax used in that link (however this did work, thanks!)

Comment: my search terms in Google were `postgres declare variable query`.  Glad it worked.