# Any tool to run an SQL query (against postgres) with :parameters without manually replacing them?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a query

```
select * from orders   where company=:company
```

And I run it by setting parameter in code.

All well and good, but what if I want to run this query in my sql tool (pgadmin for example) but I do not want to manually replace parameters with actual values (the real query has 5 paramters and is very big).

Is there a tool or a way to run the query and set parameters values somewhere so they would be used in query as if it was run from code?

If it is relevant I use C# and NHibernate (but in this case I use native SQL query) and Postgresql.

EDIT: Requirement: SQL query text should not be changed in any way, paramater should be specified with ':' character not any other way. And it should not be a command line tool (but something with visual UI).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use variables in a simple PostgreSQL script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766657/how-do-you-use-variables-in-a-simple-postgresql-script)

Comment: OK, I tried \set name=value example, cannot get it to work in pgadmin, I guess I am missing something?

Comment: `\set` is a `psql` meta command

Comment: Thanks you for clarification. So is there a way to do what I asked from any visual sql tool (not pgadmin specifically any will do)

Comment: The first comment in that question suggests using DO for inline functions. Exactly what you need.

Comment: @Jakub That answer is not adequate since an anonymous code block does not return anything other than `void`. I wonder how did that answer get so many votes.

Comment: Of course they can return things, you just have to be creative about it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to wrap the query in a function

```
create function f(_company text)
returns setof orders as $$
    select *
    from orders
    where company = _company
;
$$ language sql;
```

Then use it like this in the graphical client

```
select * from f('company name');
```

And in the C# client use it with the same parameter syntax:

```
select * from f(:company);
```

The use of functions will simplify your code. They are reusable. There is no need to rebuild the application if only the function was changed.

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain my question good enough. But what I want to do is not to change the syntax of a sql query at all (leave parameter as :company) and run it like that. It is just a productivity thing, for saving time, not actual programming task. I just thought that maybe there is some tool that can do that out of the box.

Comment: @deafsheep I understand that. The `create function` code will not be in your code. Just the `select`. Check the update.

Comment: This is an interesting variation and it technically fits what I asked, but you need to create function on server, which is an additional requirement. Thanks you very much for your answer but I was looking for more of "UI" way of doing this. Maybe the question is too vague and I should close it...

Answer (score 0):

You created a problem that doesn't really exist. If you really must use something diffrent for writing your query then anonymous blocks are the best solution:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foobar;
DO $$
DECLARE _foo TEXT;
DECLARE _bar TEXT;
BEGIN
  _foo := 'foo' ;
  _bar := 'bar' ;
  CREATE TEMP TABLE foobar AS SELECT _foo, _bar;
END $$;
SELECT * FROM foobar;
```

You get 5 additional lines + 2 lines for each variable. When you're happy just do a find and replace of " _" into " :" and you will have your query.