# SQL: Printing from an UPDATE command

Tags: postgresql

Lets say that I have a simple SQL script:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET data = new_data
WHERE my_table.data IS NULL;
```

I would like to print which id's that where updated in the UPDATE command. So something like this functionality-wise:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET data = new_data, RAISE NOTICE 'Updated %', my_table.id
WHERE my_table.data IS NULL;
```

Is this possible? I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: You want to *return* the IDs, not print them. Printing means send a text message to the client.

Comment: No, I want to print them as I am debugging my code - in the same way as I normally do with RAISE NOTICE from my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I came up with something like this.

```
DO language plpgsql $$
DECLARE _id bigint;
BEGIN
    FOR _id IN
    WITH up AS (
      UPDATE my_table
        SET data = new_data
        WHERE data IS NULL
        RETURNING id)
    SELECT id from up
    LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE 'Updated %', _id;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

It is a bit clumsy, but should work for you.

At first, `RAISE NOTICE` has to be wrapped like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6990059/6385043). I found no way how to store multiple rows (`...RETURNING id`) into variables, which might not be possible with current versions. That's why I let a select follow the update, which itself feeds the `RAISE` you require.

Answer (score 1):

You can return use the `RETURNING` clause of the [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html) statement to return values from each updated row. From the documentation's example:

```
UPDATE weather SET temp_lo = temp_lo+1, temp_hi = temp_lo+15, prcp = DEFAULT
  WHERE city = 'San Francisco' AND date = '2003-07-03'
  RETURNING temp_lo, temp_hi, prcp;
```

This will return the updated temperatures.

In your case you could try:

```
UPDATE my_table
 SET data = new_data
 WHERE my_table.data IS NULL
 RETURNING id;
```

Comment: This does not answer my question: How do I print the id's that were updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the updated rows ID then Try like this,

For Update:

```
 UPDATE my_table SET col2 = val2 WHERE col1 = val1 RETURNING ID;
```

For Insert:

INSERT INTO my_table (col2) values ( val2 ) RETURNING ID;

Comment: This does not answer my question: How do I print the id's that were updated?