# How to declare a variable in postgres script?

Tags: postgresql

I am fairly new to Postgres and I cannot believe how difficult I am finding just to declare a variable. I did come across other SO posts, but none of them helped in my situation. All I want is to write the a script like below in postgres:

```
declare @age int = 10;

select * from person p where p.age > @age;
```

Based on the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766657/how-do-you-use-variables-in-a-simple-postgresql-script), I tried:

```
DO
$$
    DECLARE
        overTheAgeOf int := 15;
    BEGIN
        select *
        from person
        where age > overTheAgeOf;
    END
$$;
```

This gives me error: `[42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data`

Then I tried returning the result of the script:

```
return (select *
    from person
    where age > overTheAgeOf);
```

That gave me another error: `ERROR: RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void`

How do declare a variable and use it in script(s) that follows?

Comment: SQL has not variables. They are typically provided by the SQL client - which tool do you use to run the script?

Comment: I was using DataGrip.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are confused on several levels.

1. There is the query language SQL, and there is the procedural language PL/pgSQL. The only connection is that

   - you can run SQL statements from PL/pgSQL code
   - you can have PL/pgSQL code in the body of the SQL statements `DO` and `CREATE FUNCTION/PROCEDURE`.
2. There are variables in PL/pgSQL, which are defined in the `DECLARE` section, but there are no variables in SQL.
3. `DO` statements cannot return any values.

If you want to use PL/pgSQL variables, and you want to return values, you'll have to use a function. An example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getpersons() RETURNS SETOF person
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   overTheAgeOf int := 15;
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
       SELECT *
       FROM person
       WHERE age > overTheAgeOf;
END;$$;

SELECT getpersons();
```

There is the alternative of using variables on the client. With the `psql` client, you could use:

```
\set overTheAgeOf 15

SELECT *
FROM person
WHERE age > :overTheAgeOf;
```

Answer (score 6):

The good structure is like this :

```
DO
 LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
DECLARE
  variable int := 0;
BEGIN
    -- your code
    raise notice '%', variable::varchar;
END;
$$;
```