# Return variable in postgres select

Tags: postgresql

This covers most use cases [How do you use variables in a simple PostgreSQL script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766657) but not the select clause.

This code produces an error `column "ct" does not exist"`

```
DO
$$

declare CT timestamp := '2020-09-04 23:59:59';

select CT,5 from job;

$$;
```

I can see why it would interpret CT as a column name. What's the Postgres syntax required to refer to a variable in the context of the select clause?

I would expect that query to return

```
'2020-09-04 23:59:59',5
```

for each row in the job table.

---

## Addendum to the accepted answer

My use case doesn't return rows. Instead, the result of the select is consumed by an insert statement. I'm transforming rows from staging tables into other tables and adding value like the import date and the identity owning the inserts. It's these values that are provided by the variables - they are used in several such transforms and the point of the variable is to let me set each value once up the top of the script.

Because the rows are consumed like this, it turns out that I don't need a function wrapping this code. It's a bit inconvenient to test since I can't run the select and look at the outcome without copying it and pasting in literals, but at least it's possible to use variables. My working script looks like this:

```sql
do
$$
declare ct timestamp := '2020-09-04 23:59:59';
declare cb int := 2;
declare iso8601 varchar(50) := 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
declare USAdate varchar(50) := 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
begin

delete from dozer_wheel_loader_equipment_movement where created = ct;
INSERT INTO dozer_wheel_loader_equipment_movement 
(site, primary_category_id, machine, machine_class, x, y, z, timestamp_local, created, created_by)
select site ,mc.id ,machine , machineclass ,x,y,z,to_timestamp(timestamplocal, iso8601), ct, cb 
from stage_dozer_csv d join machine_category mc on d.primarycategory = mc.short_code;
...
end
$$
```

There is a lot of worthwhile related reading at [How to declare a variable in a PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490942)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16552441

Comment: Are you not getting `SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "CT" is ambiguous` error message? I do not think that you can resolve this. Put a prefix to the variable name like var_ct and then `select var_ct, 5 from job;` would give you the desired result. Btw your pl/pgsql block is invalid.

Comment: `declare` starts a _block_ for declaration. It's only needed once. Creating a new `declare` block for each variable is inefficient and not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things about variables in PostgreSQL.

Variable can not be used in Plain SQL in Postgres. So you have to use any pl language i.e. `plpgsql` to use this. You have tried the same in your example.

In your `DO` block you have missed the `Begin` and `End`, So you have to write it like below

```
DO
$$
begin
declare CT timestamp := '2020-09-04 23:59:59';
select CT,5 from job;
end
$$;
```

But when you read the official documentation of [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-do.html) Statement, it says `DO` will allow to run the anonymous code but it returns `void`, that's why above code will throw following error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
```

So there is only one way - wrap this code block in a `Function` like below:

```sql
create or replace function func() returns table(col1 timestamp, col2 int )
AS
$$
declare ct timestamp := '2020-09-04 23:59:59';
begin
return query
select CT,5 from job;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

and you can call it like below:

```sql
select * from func()
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b3f9101a6631875d1e5d45673754902d)

**Conclusion**

1. You can not use `variable` in normal SQL statement in Postgres.
2. You have to use any Procedural Language i.e. `plpgsql` to use variable.
3. `DO` Block doesn't return any value so you can not use select statement like above in `DO` block. It is good for non-returning queries i.e. `insert`, `update`, `delete` or `grant` etc.
4. Only way to return a value from procedural language code block is - you have to wrap it in a suitable PostgreSQL Function.