# How to run a function without storing it postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Sorry I'm pretty new on this i would like to run something like the code  but without storing it, just output the data as i am a read only user in the database I want to run it. BTW i know that the code there is very simple. I just wanna know how to print the data as it is an example.

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION a ()
RETURNS timestamp
LANGUAGE plpgsql   
AS $variable_name$     
DECLARE 
  time_a timestamp; 
BEGIN     
  SELECT facilitytime 
     INTO time_a 
  FROM metrics 
  ORDER BY facilitytime DESC 
  LIMIT 1;   

  RETURN time_a;
END;    
$$
```

Comment: Use `select a()` to "print" the result

Comment: Sorry but that would store it, right? I would like to output the data directly

Comment: Then run the SELECT statement directly

Comment: There is were i have a problem as i want to use variables and multiple selects

Comment: Then describe _that_ problem, not some code you aren't actually using.

Comment: It is that code but with more selects a variables

Comment: I think what you are looking for is anonymous code blocks (available since PG 9).  Look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766657/how-do-you-use-variables-in-a-simple-postgresql-script) for some examples

Comment: @JonathanWillcock,. Except `DO`(anonymous) functions can't return values, you either have to 1) `RAISE NOTICE` in the function or 2) Inside  the function  `INSERT/UPDATE` the values into a table, which the OP says they can't do.

Comment: It seems me given the restrictions, that you need to create a function outside the database in the language of your choice.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes it was `RAISE NOTICE` that I had in mind.  The link I gave contained at least one example